# How do I check that a number is float or integer?

Tags: javascript, types, numbers

How to find that a number is `float` or `integer`?

```
1.25 --> float  
1 --> integer  
0 --> integer  
0.25 --> float
```

Comment: I understand what you're asking here, but just to be clear: `<nit-pick>` JavaScript does not have different integer and float numeric types. Every number in JavaScript is just a `Number`. `</nit-pick>`

Comment: Is `Infinity`an integer or a non-integer value as far as you're concerned?  The answers here are pretty evenly distributed on this score.

Comment: @MikeSamuel To be mathematically accurate: since infinity is not a real number and all integers are real numbers, `Infinity` cannot be considered an integer.

Comment: @rvighne, The question asks about "float", not "real".  Either way, reals are irrelevant because computers can only represent [computable numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number).

Comment: @MikeSamuel Sorry, I meant integers *and floats* are real numbers. And anyway, I said that ints and floats are **part of** real numbers, not that they can represent all reals. Basically, my point is that Infinity is not a number and you shouldn't care whether it's a float or int.

Comment: @rvighne, I think we agree that the fact that the infinities and NaN are not real numbers means that IEEE-754 floats are not a subset of real numbers.  All numerical analysis based on IEEE-754 has to deal with this fact.  What I don't understand is how you think this fact determines how is_integral should behave w.r.t. cardinalities.  Personally, I think ((x % 1) == 0) is a good proxy and is fully specified by IEEE-754, so there's no need to argue about correspondances between different number lines.

Comment: @Mike "The IEEE 754 “remainder” operation computes the remainder from a rounding division, not a truncating division, and so its behaviour is not analogous to that of the usual integer remainder operator. Instead the ECMAScript language defines % on floating-point operations to behave in a manner analogous to that of the Java integer remainder operator; this may be compared with the C library function fmod."  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: Counting can only be done with integers so countable infinity is a integer. nb Cantor proved there are more real numbers than a countable infinite set. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountablyInfinite.html)

Comment: A good paper on the floating point specs.  https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

Comment: You can use the Number method `isInteger`. Check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/htLVw - a benchmark for the common ways to do it

Comment: Do you consider `1.0` integer or float?

Answer (score 1505, accepted):

check for a remainder when dividing by 1:

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

If you don't know that the argument is a number you need two tests:

```
function isInt(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
}

function isFloat(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}
```

**Update 2019**
5 years after this answer was written, a solution was standardized in ECMA Script 2015. That solution is covered [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20779354/1153227).

Comment: Careful, this will also return true for an empty string, a string representing an integral number, `true`, `false`, `null`, an empty array, an array containing a single integral number, an array containing a string representing an integral number, and maybe more.

Comment: I think your first implementation is brilliant and efficient and the second redundant. Right?

Comment: Just to note, this method will work in most cases, but its not enough to assume that the converse (!isInt) implies a float. Try it against a very large number - !isInt(Number.MAX_VALUE-0.1)- it won't work. This is due to the use of modulo. The methods in the answer below this *will* work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, even if JavaScript does not differ between float and int, this is extremely useful for translation: http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Comment: Nice trick but not the correct answer as it fails to check empty string `""` and `1.0` `isInt("");` && `isInt(1.0);` both result in `true` see this demo http://jsbin.com/elohuq/1/edit

Comment: Why the use of === vs == ?

Comment: Ina, the use of === is encouraged over == in general, because it leads to more type safety and more predictable, uniform behaviour.

As previous answerers have stated, this answer is absolutely, 100% incorrect. The values null, empty string, 1.0 and numerous others will all register incorrectly as integers (even with the === check).

Comment: isInt(1.000000000000000000000000001) === true

Comment: It's an accepted answer with 383 thumbs up right now but it's just wrong. I mean, it's like a workaround that doesn't take you where you wanted to go. It's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Worst answer on SO? `null % 1 === 0`, `[] % 1 === 0`

Comment: The question was how to check if a number is an integer, not how to check any value.

Comment: would you still use it or go for the new Number.isInteger() ?

Comment: it's not wrong. 1.000000000000000000000000001 === 1

Comment: Wrong for reasons described above. It validates an empty input field as containing an integer.

Comment: Note that second `isInt` may got `false` with `isInt(new Number(0))`.

Comment: `4ff` returns true. Is that expected?

Comment: May i ask why you use `Number(n) === n` and not `typeof n === "number"`? I guess it depends on the intention what you use, but the first also is true if `n === "5"`, for example.

Comment: does not work for me. n === Number(n) always fail and returns false.

Comment: A lot of hostile comments about how it doesn't validate strings. That's not part of the OP's question. If I go onto SO to ask a question about retrieving the last element of an array and someone answers with `function last (array) { return array[array.length - 1]; }`, is it "just wrong" or "Worst answer on SO" because it doesn't check if the argument is an array first? Yes, good practice to check arguments, but that's developer responsibility. SO answers should be short and directly answer the question as clearly as possible.

Comment: It does not work with using ===. At least, in Firefox. But it DOES work, if to use ==.

Comment: This is invalid code and will fail with numbers like 1.2 because this number become close-to 1.2 but not 1.2 `test: 1.2 false ::: 0.19999999999999996`

Comment: pretty sure that is modulus % and not dividing /

Comment: `1.0 % 1 !== 0` return false

Answer (score 172):

There is a method called `Number.isInteger()` which is currently implemented in everything but IE. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Polyfill) also provides a polyfill for other browsers:

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && 
    isFinite(value) && 
    Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

However, for most uses cases, you are better off using `Number.isSafeInteger`   which also checks if the value is so high/low that any decimal places would have been lost anyway. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger#Polyfill) has a polyfil for this as well. (You also need the `isInteger` pollyfill above.)

```
if (!Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
    Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991; // Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
}
Number.isSafeInteger = Number.isSafeInteger || function (value) {
   return Number.isInteger(value) && Math.abs(value) <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
};
```

Comment: This works in my Chrome now too and probably the way to go in the future

Comment: In my opinion the best solution.

Comment: `Number.isInteger(12.0) //true` (Chrome, Feb '17)

Comment: This with the polyfill is the most reliable and simple solution.

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov `12.0 ∈ ℤ`.

Comment: I'm unaware if the spec has changed since this answer was provided, but note that the above function is not a correct polyfill for `Number.isInteger`. It is, however, a correct polyfill for `Number.isSafeInteger`.

`Number.isInteger` should not check whether the number is a "safe integer". See on MDN: [isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Polyfill) and [isSafeInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger#Polyfill).

Comment: @Bravo I read too quickly, I though he wanted to use that to know if the value was (float || integer), like 2 checks in one method.

Comment: Number.isSafeInteger(1.00000000000000011) // true
Number.isSafeInteger(1.00000000000000012) // false

Welcome to JS

Answer (score 167):

Try these functions to test whether a value is a number primitive value that has no fractional part and is within the size limits of what can be represented as an exact integer.

```
function isFloat(n) {
    return n === +n && n !== (n|0);
}

function isInteger(n) {
    return n === +n && n === (n|0);
}
```

Comment: heh awesom exploit, it's pretty much mine (`n===+n` to check for numeric, `n|0` to round), but with built-in operators. funky

Comment: @John Hartsock a string is never going to be a numeric value.  It's a string.  The point of this function is to test whether a value is a Javascript numeric value that has no fractional part and is within the size limits of what can be represented as an exact integer. If you want to check a string to see if it contains a sequence of characters that represent a number, you'd call `parseFloat()` first.

Comment: @Pointy but parseFloat("1.1a") will still return 1.1.  Suppose you had a text field you wanted to validate that it was an float and only a float without alpha characters.  Testing weather a text field from an input element for decimal(float)

Comment: @John Hartsock: it won't return true unless a number primitive was passed. I think that makes sense given the names of the functions. Anything else should be a candidate for isString, isBoolean, etc. if such functions are being written.

Comment: @Pointy: double precision floats can represent integer values exactly up to 2^53. So it depends if the OP was asking about integer in the maths sense (whole numbers) or in the 32-bit data sense. If it's the latter, your solution is perfect.

Comment: @Dave yes that's true, but note that when JavaScript wants to deal with integers it usually bashes them down to 32 bits.

Comment: +1 for using `n|0` to convert the value to a signed 32-bit integer. As @Dave says, the integers between 2^31 and 2^53 are interesting in JavaScript, because they can be represented exactly, but get truncated to their least-significant 32 bits by the bitwise operators.

Comment: @DaggNabbit I've never seen `===+` or `|` in JavaScript before. I understand what @Claudiu said about them but I don't see them mentioned anywhere on w3school. Is there a place I can go to see some documentation on them? I'm going to guess `|` is a bit wise operator, is that right? Is `===+` some kind of addition or maybe its a positive sign operator which would only work on a number? Again I can't find anything about these anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan: `===+` is actually two operators, `===` (strict equality), and then [unary `+`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators), e.g. `(+5)`. the `|` is [bit-wise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), yes.

Comment: @Dan, Claudiu is right, `===+` was just my lazy formatting. It's fixed now, with Pointy's excellent comment added. Also, w3schools is generally considered to be inaccurate and incomplete; you probably don't want to use it for a reference. Better to stick to docs from MDN, WHATWG, W3C, and the official spec.

Comment: The only caveat with this method is that bitwise operators in JavaScript work up until 32 bits, so large numbers will give false as an integer.

Comment: @GastónSánchez ISTM if a number cannot be expressed as an unsigned 32-bit int, it is not an "integer" in the context of JavaScript. IOW the only way this question is useful is if it's asking how to identify numbers that can be converted to the format required by bitwise operators without changing their value. Determining whether a number has no fractional part is trivial; I assume that's not what was being asked here.

Comment: in javascript, bitwise operators like `|` (OR) only operate on signed 32-bit integers. OP does not state if the goal is to check for signed int32 values. So this won't work with out of range numbers. `isInteger(5000000000)` will return `false` which is wrong!

Comment: @OnurYıldırım see comments above. This answer assumes the OP is asking how to determine if a number can be represented as a 32 bit unsigned int.

Comment: @DaggNabbit well, `isInteger(-1000)` will return `true` which is not an unsigned integer.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım doh, I meant signed.

Comment: `n === +n` is redundant in integer test, no?

Comment: Seems like `1.0` is rejected as a float: `1.0 === +1.0 && 1.0 !== (1.0|0)` >>> `false`.

Comment: Funny occasion when this doesn't work is when you use `Number`.

Comment: isFloat(12.0) is false .. ?

Answer (score 94):

Why not something like this:

```
var isInt = function(n) { return parseInt(n) === n };
```

Comment: This is actually the core of a good solution for me. I needed to allow positive integers and disallow floats, strings and negative integers.

Comment: This seems like a vastly better solution than the others in this thread. Could the community offer some criticism, perhaps?

Comment: var y = 1.00; y === parseInt(y, 10); // this returns true for me, which is not really what we want.

Comment: The only "downside" I see is that the given number `n` is converted to a string by `parseInt`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). But I will use this solution. :)

Comment: why is that a downside? it's just converted for comparison

Comment: isInt(1,02) - returns true, but should return false

Comment: @ekussberg: Why should that return false? 1 is an int. and 02, the second argument, is ignored.

Comment: @Flimzy Some countries use a comma `,` to separate whole number from decimal.  Maybe this was the case and @ekussberg made a typo.  If it was `1.02`, it would be false as expected.  `,` is an operator in JavaScript.

Comment: What if the number is very large? parseInt first convert the argument to String, then check if the beginning of the string may convert to some integer. for example, 1e100 is an integer, but `parseInt(1e100)` will got `1` instead of `1e100` which will fail in your solution.

Comment: This fails if input type is string. Eg: If n="750" it returns false.

Comment: THIS is what I am looking for! I used this one like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54866825/7265539) for my project. Perfect!

Comment: −1 because converting a number to a string and then parsing it back to a number just to check whether that results in the same value is a ridiculous amount of complexity when all that’s really needed is to check whether a number—already in floating-point form!—is an integer.

Answer (score 32):

You can use a simple regular expression:

```
function isInt(value) {

    var er = /^-?[0-9]+$/;

    return er.test(value);
}
```

Or you can use the below functions too, according your needs. They are developed by the [PHPJS Project](http://www.phpjs.org).

[`is_int()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_int:444) => Check if variable type is integer and if its content is integer

[`is_float()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_float:442) => Check if variable type is float and if its content is float

[`ctype_digit()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_float:442) => Check if variable type is string and if its content has only decimal digits

**Update 1**

Now it checks negative numbers too, thanks for [@ChrisBartley comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer/10303985?noredirect=1#comment35614627_10303985)!

Comment: Perfect to test simple unsigned integers.

Comment: One liner: `/^[0-9]+$/.test(String(value))`

Comment: Shorter and slightly less readable one-liner: `/^[0-9]+$/.test(''+value)`

Comment: Doesn't handle negative integers.  You don't need the ternary operator either since test() returns a boolean.  This should do it: `return /^-?\d+$/.test(String(value));`

Comment: @ChrisBartley, Thanks! I made an update, including your credits. Please check if everything is okay now.

Comment: This is only 1/2 the answer. Question clearly says `float` or `integer`.

Comment: @Rocco, I talked about the [is_float()](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_float:442) function, so i think the answer is complete

Comment: Regex will be always slower than other methods.

Answer (score 20):

```
function isInteger(x) { return typeof x === "number" && isFinite(x) && Math.floor(x) === x; }
function isFloat(x) { return !!(x % 1); }

// give it a spin

isInteger(1.0);        // true
isFloat(1.0);          // false
isFloat(1.2);          // true
isInteger(1.2);        // false
isFloat(1);            // false
isInteger(1);          // true    
isFloat(2e+2);         // false
isInteger(2e+2);       // true
isFloat('1');          // false
isInteger('1');        // false
isFloat(NaN);          // false
isInteger(NaN);        // false
isFloat(null);         // false
isInteger(null);       // false
isFloat(undefined);    // false
isInteger(undefined);  // false
```

Comment: Apparently, floats that end with .0 are automatically cast to Int in JavaScript.

Comment: failed with `1.2`. Always test numeric functions with 0.1 0.2 0.3

Comment: @LukasLiesis not for me.

Comment: There is no need for any of the strict equality operators here.

Comment: isFloat(1563457121531) returns false

Answer (score 19):

Here are efficient functions that check if the value is a number or can be *safely converted to* a number:

```
function isNumber(value) {
    if ((undefined === value) || (null === value)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof value == 'number') {
        return true;
    }
    return !isNaN(value - 0);
}
```

And for integers (would return false if the value is a float):

```
function isInteger(value) {
    if ((undefined === value) || (null === value)) {
        return false;
    }
    return value % 1 == 0;
}
```

The efficiency here is that parseInt (or parseNumber) are avoided when the value already is a number. Both parsing functions *always* convert to string first and then attempt to parse that string, which would be a waste if the value already is a number.

Thank you to the other posts here for providing further ideas for optimization!

Comment: This function fails on the empty string: isNumber('') is true.

Answer (score 14):

2022 update - We could simply use the Number's methods.

Check if integer or float :
`Number.isFinite(val)`

Check if integer :
`Number.isInteger(val)`

Check if float (not integer) : `!Number.isInteger(val) && Number.isFinite(val)`

Answer (score 12):

```
function isInt(n) 
{
    return n != "" && !isNaN(n) && Math.round(n) == n;
}
function isFloat(n){
    return n != "" && !isNaN(n) && Math.round(n) != n;
}
```

works for all cases.

Comment: +1 This is good. `isInt('1')` returns `true` as expected (at least for me). Weird enough, though, this returns `true` to `isInt([5])` as well. Didn't matter for me, but may for you, so, take care.

Comment: isFloat(12.0) is false

Answer (score 8):

How about this one?

```
isFloat(num) {
    return typeof num === "number" && !Number.isInteger(num);
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(isFloat(1.0));` results false.

Comment: `isFloat(NaN)` and `isFloat(Infinity)` returns true :/

Answer (score 8):

We can check by `isInteger` function.
ie number will return true and float return false

> ```
> console.log(Number.isInteger(2)),<BR>
> ```
>
> Will return true

> ```
> console.log(Number.isInteger(2.5))
> ```
>
> Will return false

Comment: But `Number.isInteger(2.0)` also returns `true`

Answer (score 7):

As others mentioned, you only have doubles in JS. So how do you define a number being an integer? Just check if the rounded number is equal to itself:

```
function isInteger(f) {
    return typeof(f)==="number" && Math.round(f) == f;
}
function isFloat(f) { return typeof(f)==="number" && !isInteger(f); }
```

Comment: Might want to check that the value is numeric... `isFloat('abc')` returns `true`

Comment: `isFloat(NaN) // true`

Comment: @shime: Good catch. NaN is technically a floating point number though... depends what the use case is I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I use for integers:

```
Math.ceil(parseFloat(val)) === val
```

Short, nice :) Works all the time. This is what David Flanagan suggests if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I like this one because it's a short, simple answer that doesn't rely on cryptic bitwise operations.

Comment: Why `parseFloat` ?

Answer (score 6):

##### Simple integer test:

```
if( n === parseInt(n) ) ...
```

Makes sense: if JavaScript can convert something to an integer, and by the conversion it becomes the exact same thing, then your operand was an integer.

##### Test cases for console:

```
x = 1;     x===parseInt(x); // true
x = "1";   x===parseInt(x); // false
x = 1.1;   x===parseInt(x); // false, obviously

// BUT!

x = 1.0;   x===parseInt(x); // true, because 1.0 is NOT a float!
```

This confuses a lot of people.  Whenever something is .0, it's not a float anymore.  It's an integer.  Or you can just call it "a numeric thing" for there is no strict distinction like back then in C.  Good old times.

So basically, all you can do is check for integer accepting the fact that 1.000 is an integer.

##### Interesting side note

There was a comment about huge numbers.  Huge numbers mean NO problem for this approach; whenever parseInt is unable to handle the number (for it's too big) it will return something else than the actual value so the test will return FALSE. Look:

```
var a = 99999999999999999999;
var b = 999999999999999999999; // just one more 9 will kill the show!

var aIsInteger = (  a===parseInt(a)  )?"a is ok":"a fails";
var bIsInteger = (  b===parseInt(b)  )?"b is ok":"b fails";

alert(aIsInteger+"; "+bIsInteger);
```

I tested this in 2014 on IE8, then 2021 on Chrome, both returns "a is ok; b fails" which means if a number is too big, it can't be an integer anymore.

*20 digits ought to be enough for anybody*, to quote a classic.

Comment: This is fine if you only need to check for integral numbers (from a math POV), but if you want to make sure they actually *work like integers* (from a computing POV) it's going to be incorrect for huge numbers. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer/3885844#comment11785178_3885844).

Comment: Mmmmmmm... Why do you think that? I mean, if parseInt returns something and it seems equal to the variable itself, you can be sure your n truly does work as an integer.  I found that 99999999999999999999 (that is, 20 times "9") is a number while adding one more "9" makes parseInt fail (returning 1). It may be browser-dependent; however, YES, there is a limit and NO, whatever is off that limit won't return true for the check above.

Comment: What I mean is that bitwise operators (which treat numbers as 32 bit ints) won't give the expected results on numbers which can't be represented as 32 bit ints, so those numbers shouldn't be identified as ints. This is in line with how the proposed `Number.isInteger` works.

Comment: Something can be a true integer without being stored one specific way. I see your point but integers are integers because they don't have a fractional part and can be added/subtracted arbitrarily without getting float-like results. If you treat numbers as bitfields you're supposing something about how they're stored which is - in my opinion - a practically working but not 100% reliable way. If you're looking for "an integer stored in a certain way", well, I'm not sure there is a single-line test you can safely use on all platforms.

Comment: Numbers which can be expressed as 32-bit ints do work 100% reliably with bitwise operators. You are not "supposing anything about how they are stored;" the numbers are converted to signed 32-bit big-endian two's complement integers, per specification. Numbers which cannot be represented in this format should not be considered integers. Again, this is in line with how `Number.isInteger` works. A single line test is `n === (n | 0)` as shown in another answer.

Comment: I don't think this is correct (they're NOT 32 bit ints but 64 bit floats "per specification"); also I don't think our argument here has any added value regarding to the original question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As I wrote above, [numbers are *converted* to 32-bit ints when used with bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Numbers which cannot retain their original value when converted to 32-bit ints are not considered integers according to `Number.isInteger`. Any hand-rolled solution should also not consider such numbers to be integers. The value we've added here is in debunking incorrect solutions. You're welcome.

Comment: Integer doesn't mean "a certain kind of variable" here, since types are loose. Integer means "a float with zero fractional part". In bitwise operations, you have limitations but that's completely offtopic here. The question clearly aimed one thing, you're talking about another; a special case that is probably irrelevant. It doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Taking a closer look at `Number.isInteger`, it's capped at +/- 2^53, so it does consider numbers outside the range of 32-bit ints to also be integers (but does not consider numbers that are big/small enough to lose precision -- "unsafe integers" -- as integers). In my experience, when people talk about integers in JavaScript, they are talking about numbers that can be expressed as 32-bit unsigned ints, since all parts of the language where integers matter use this format. Maybe the OP was talking about something different, who knows (but then the question is trivial).

Comment: I was surprised too, it really seemed trivial - but I think the asker didn't know that ints are floats in js. Bitwise operations with big numbers are quite uncommon, at least I rarely use them. In other languages I've always seen 32-bit ints called "integer" so I see your point; but as for js, I simply never tried how far the precision goes. I just supposed it's way beyond 32 bits and trusted all numbers to be addition-safe.

Answer (score 5):

Any Float number with a zero decimal part (e.g. 1.0, 12.00, 0.0) are implicitly cast to Integer, so it is not possible to check if they are Float or not.

Answer (score 5):

```
!!(24%1) // false
!!(24.2%1) // true
```

Comment: `!!(24.0%1)` is false

Answer (score 5):

```
var isInt = function (n) { return n === (n | 0); };
```

Haven't had a case where this didn't do the job.

Comment: hey sorry why this returns false? 
console.log(isInt(7932938942839482938));

Comment: Because that's exceeding MaxInt.

Comment: but you can set an Int max length nope? what if i dunno the int length is returned?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but you can read more about numbers here http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5.
For handling big ints you could look into a library like https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum

Comment: This code fails for integers that are less than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, but greater than 2^32. :-(

Comment: @ekussberg Yes because `2` is an integer and `23` is considered a second argument to the function. In javascript decimals are written using dot as separator - so it should be `2.23`.

Comment: Or it's a great opportunity to learn about bitwise operations. You will gain a lot of benefit from that going forward.

Answer (score 5):

Trying some of the answers here I ended up writing this solution.
This works also with numbers inside a string.

```
function isInt(number) {
    if (!/^["|']{0,1}[-]{0,1}\d{0,}(\.{0,1}\d+)["|']{0,1}$/.test(number)) return false;
    return !(number - parseInt(number));
}

function isFloat(number) {
    if (!/^["|']{0,1}[-]{0,1}\d{0,}(\.{0,1}\d+)["|']{0,1}$/.test(number)) return false;
    return number - parseInt(number) ? true : false;
}
```

```js
    var tests = {
        'integer' : 1,
        'float' : 1.1,
        'integerInString' : '5',
        'floatInString' : '5.5',
        'negativeInt' : -345,
        'negativeFloat' : -34.98,
        'negativeIntString' : '-45',
        'negativeFloatString' : '-23.09',
        'notValidFalse' : false,
        'notValidTrue' : true,
        'notValidString' : '45lorem',
        'notValidStringFloat' : '4.5lorem',
        'notValidNan' : NaN,
        'notValidObj' : {},
        'notValidArr' : [1,2],
    };

    function isInt(number) {
        if(!/^["|']{0,1}[-]{0,1}\d{0,}(\.{0,1}\d+)["|']{0,1}$/.test(number)) return false;
        return !(number - parseInt(number));
    }
    
    function isFloat(number) {
        if(!/^["|']{0,1}[-]{0,1}\d{0,}(\.{0,1}\d+)["|']{0,1}$/.test(number)) return false;
        return number - parseInt(number) ? true : false;
    }

    function testFunctions(obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        var values = Object.values(obj);

        values.forEach(function(element, index){
            console.log(`Is ${keys[index]} (${element}) var an integer? ${isInt(element)}`);
            console.log(`Is ${keys[index]} (${element}) var a float? ${isFloat(element)}`);
        });
    }

    testFunctions(tests);
```

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to "emulate" strongly typed languages then I suggest you not trying. As others mentioned all numbers have the same representation (the same type).

Using something like *Claudiu* provided:

`isInteger( 1.0 )` -> true

which looks fine for common sense, but in something like C you would get `false`

Answer (score 3):

```
function isInteger(n) {
   return ((typeof n==='number')&&(n%1===0));
}

function isFloat(n) {
   return ((typeof n==='number')&&(n%1!==0));
}

function isNumber(n) {
   return (typeof n==='number');
}
```

Comment: An integer isn't a float? News to me.

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't have to be so complicated. The numeric value of an integer's parseFloat() and parseInt() equivalents will be the same. Thus you can do like so:

```
function isInt(value){ 
    return (parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value);
}
```

Then

```
if (isInt(x)) // do work
```

This will also allow for string checks and thus is not strict. If want a strong type solution (aka, wont work with strings):

```
function is_int(value){ return !isNaN(parseInt(value * 1) }
```

Comment: isInteger(12.0) is true

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS FINAL CODE FOR CHECK BOTH INT AND FLOAT

```
function isInt(n) { 
   if(typeof n == 'number' && Math.Round(n) % 1 == 0) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

OR

```
function isInt(n) {   
   return typeof n == 'number' && Math.Round(n) % 1 == 0;   
}
```

Comment: This only tests for float if n happens to be a number

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="number_id"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
  </form>
  <p id="message"></p>
  <script>
    var flt=document.getElementById("number_id").value;
    if(isNaN(flt)==false && Number.isInteger(flt)==false)
    {
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="the number_id is a float ";
    }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="the number_id is a Integer";
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
let n;
return (n = value % 1) !== 0 && !isNaN(n);
```

when the return value is false means the input value is float number or float string, otherwise the input value is integer numbef or integer string.

basically it needs to check the precision value for not equal to zero.

another one is to check the correct string number also.

Comment: Review: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer might technically be correct, I'm failing to see how it is substantially different from other answers here. Therefore I'm voting to delete it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
const integerCheck = (num) => {
        const isInt = (n) => Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0
        const isFloat = (n) => Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0
        return (isInt(num) || !isFloat(num))        
}
console.log( integerCheck('23.3') );
```

Comment: I don't understand the design philosophy here. There's no need to use lambdas at all. You're also doing many redundant calculations. There are 48 other answers here. What distinguishes this one from the others?

Answer (score 2):

Compare that [`floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) result is not the same as [`ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) result.

```js
const isFloat = v => !isNaN(v) && Math.floor(v) !== Math.ceil(v);
```

```
> isFloat(1)
= false

> isFloat(1.1)
= true

> isFloat(42)
= false

> isFloat(84.42)
= true
```

Comment: Problem with this is that isFloat("myString") returns true

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli Thank you for informing me of this problem. I've updated the answer, can you verify this fixes the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For integers I use this

```
function integer_or_null(value) {
    if ((undefined === value) || (null === value)) {
        return null;
    }
    if(value % 1 != 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java script all the numbers are `internally 64 bit floating point`, same as double in java.
There are no diffrent types in javascript, all are represented by type `number`. Hence you wil l not be able make a `instanceof` check. However u can use the above solutions given to find out if it is a fractional number. designers of java script felt with a single type they can avoid numerous type cast errors.

Answer (score 1):

For those curious, using Benchmark.js I tested the most up-voted answers (and the one posted today) on this post, here are my results:

```
var n = -10.4375892034758293405790;
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
suite
    // kennebec
    .add('0', function() {
        return n % 1 == 0;
    })
    // kennebec
    .add('1', function() {
        return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
    })
    // kennebec
    .add('2', function() {
        return typeof n === 'number' && parseFloat(n) == parseInt(n, 10) && !isNaN(n);
    })

    // Axle
    .add('3', function() {
        return n.toString().indexOf('.') === -1;
    })

    // Dagg Nabbit
    .add('4', function() {
        return n === +n && n === (n|0);
    })

    // warfares
    .add('5', function() {
        return parseInt(n) === n;
    })

    // Marcio Simao
    .add('6', function() {
        return /^-?[0-9]+$/.test(n.toString());
    })

    // Tal Liron
    .add('7', function() {
        if ((undefined === n) || (null === n)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof n == 'number') {
            return true;
        }
        return !isNaN(n - 0);
    });

// Define logs and Run
suite.on('cycle', function(event) {
    console.log(String(event.target));
}).on('complete', function() {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
}).run({ 'async': true });
```

---

```
0 x 12,832,357 ops/sec ±0.65% (90 runs sampled)
1 x 12,916,439 ops/sec ±0.62% (95 runs sampled)
2 x 2,776,583 ops/sec ±0.93% (92 runs sampled)
3 x 10,345,379 ops/sec ±0.49% (97 runs sampled)
4 x 53,766,106 ops/sec ±0.66% (93 runs sampled)
5 x 26,514,109 ops/sec ±2.72% (93 runs sampled)
6 x 10,146,270 ops/sec ±2.54% (90 runs sampled)
7 x 60,353,419 ops/sec ±0.35% (97 runs sampled)

Fastest is 7 Tal Liron
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this little function, which will return true for both positive and negative integers:

```
function isInt(val) {
    return ["string","number"].indexOf(typeof(val)) > -1 && val !== '' && !isNaN(val+".0");
}
```

This works because 1 or "1" becomes "1.0", which isNaN() returns false on (which we then negate and return), but 1.0 or "1.0" becomes "1.0.0", while "string" becomes "string.0", neither of which are numbers, so isNaN() returns false (and, again, gets negated).

If you only want positive integers, there's this variant:

```
function isPositiveInt(val) {
    return ["string","number"].indexOf(typeof(val)) > -1 && val !== '' && !isNaN("0"+val);
}
```

or, for negative integers:

```
function isNegativeInt(val) {
    return `["string","number"].indexOf(typeof(val)) > -1` && val !== '' && isNaN("0"+val);
}
```

isPositiveInt() works by moving the concatenated numeric string ahead of the value to be tested. For example, isPositiveInt(1) results in isNaN() evaluating "01", which evaluates false. Meanwhile, isPositiveInt(-1) results in isNaN() evaluating "0-1", which evaluates true. We negate the return value and that gives us what we want. isNegativeInt() works similarly, but without negating the return value of isNaN().

Edit:

My original implementation would also return true on arrays and empty strings. This implementation doe not have that defect. It also has the benefit of returning early if val is not a string or number, or if it's an empty string, making it faster in these cases. You can further modify it by replacing the first two clauses with

```
typeof(val) != "number"
```

if you only want to match literal numbers (and not strings)

Edit:

I can't post comments yet, so I'm adding this to my answer. The benchmark posted by @Asok is very informative; however, the fastest function does not fit the requirements, as it also returns TRUE for floats, arrays, booleans, and empty strings.

I created the following test suite to test each of the functions, adding my answer to the list, as well (function 8, which parses strings, and function 9, which does not):

```
funcs = [
    function(n) {
        return n % 1 == 0;
    },
    function(n) {
        return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
    },
    function(n) {
        return typeof n === 'number' && parseFloat(n) == parseInt(n, 10) && !isNaN(n);
    },
    function(n) {
        return n.toString().indexOf('.') === -1;
    },
    function(n) {
        return n === +n && n === (n|0);
    },
    function(n) {
        return parseInt(n) === n;
    },
    function(n) {
        return /^-?[0-9]+$/.test(n.toString());
    },
    function(n) {
        if ((undefined === n) || (null === n)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof n == 'number') {
            return true;
        }
        return !isNaN(n - 0);
    },
    function(n) {
        return ["string","number"].indexOf(typeof(n)) > -1 && n !== '' && !isNaN(n+".0");
    }
];
vals = [
    [1,true],
    [-1,true],
    [1.1,false],
    [-1.1,false],
    [[],false],
    [{},false],
    [true,false],
    [false,false],
    [null,false],
    ["",false],
    ["a",false],
    ["1",null],
    ["-1",null],
    ["1.1",null],
    ["-1.1",null]
];

for (var i in funcs) {
    var pass = true;
    console.log("Testing function "+i);
    for (var ii in vals) {
        var n = vals[ii][0];
        var ns;
        if (n === null) {
            ns = n+"";
        } else {
            switch (typeof(n)) {
                case "string":
                    ns = "'" + n + "'";
                    break;
                case "object":
                    ns = Object.prototype.toString.call(n);
                    break;
                default:
                    ns = n;
            }
            ns = "("+typeof(n)+") "+ns;
        }

        var x = vals[ii][1];
        var xs;
        if (x === null) {
            xs = "(ANY)";
        } else {
            switch (typeof(x)) {
                case "string":
                    xs = "'" + n + "'";
                    break;
                case "object":
                    xs = Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
                    break;
                default:
                    xs = x;
            }
            xs = "("+typeof(x)+") "+xs;
        }

        var rms;
        try {
            var r = funcs[i](n);
            var rs;
            if (r === null) {
                rs = r+"";
            } else {
                switch (typeof(r)) {
                    case "string":
                        rs = "'" + r + "'";
                        break;
                    case "object":
                        rs = Object.prototype.toString.call(r);
                        break;
                    default:
                        rs = r;
                }
                rs = "("+typeof(r)+") "+rs;
            }

            var m;
            var ms;
            if (x === null) {
                m = true;
                ms = "N/A";
            } else if (typeof(x) == 'object') {
                m = (xs === rs);
                ms = m;
            } else {
                m = (x === r);
                ms = m;
            }
            if (!m) {
                pass = false;
            }
            rms = "Result: "+rs+", Match: "+ms;
        } catch (e) {
            rms = "Test skipped; function threw exception!"
        }

        console.log("    Value: "+ns+", Expect: "+xs+", "+rms);
    }
    console.log(pass ? "PASS!" : "FAIL!");
}
```

I also reran the benchmark with function #8 added to the list. I won't post the result, as they're a bit embarrassing (e.g. that function is NOT fast)...

The (abridged -- I removed successful tests, since the output is quite long) results are as follows:

```
Testing function 0
Value: (object) [object Array], Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (boolean) true, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (boolean) false, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: null, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (string) '', Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
FAIL!

Testing function 1
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!

Testing function 2
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!

Testing function 3
Value: (object) true, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (object) false, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (boolean) [object Array], Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (boolean) [object Object], Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: null, Expect: (boolean) false, Test skipped; function threw exception!
Value: (string) '', Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (string) 'a', Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
FAIL!

Testing function 4
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!

Testing function 5
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!

Testing function 6
Value: null, Expect: (boolean) false, Test skipped; function threw exception!
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!

Testing function 7
Value: (number) 1.1, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (number) -1.1, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (object) true, Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (boolean) [object Array], Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (boolean) [object Object], Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (string) '', Expect: (boolean) false, Result: (boolean) true, Match: false
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
FAIL!

Testing function 8
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) true, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!

Testing function 9
Value: (string) '1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
Value: (string) '-1.1', Expect: (ANY), Result: (boolean) false, Match: N/A
PASS!
```

I've left in failures so you can see where each function is failing, and the (string) '#' tests so you can see how each function handles integer and float values in strings, as some may want these parsed as numbers and some may not.

Out of the 10 functions tested, the ones that actually fit OP's requirements are [1,3,5,6,8,9]

Answer (score 1):

```
function int(a) {
  return a - a === 0 && a.toString(32).indexOf('.') === -1
}

function float(a) {
  return a - a === 0 && a.toString(32).indexOf('.') !== -1
}
```

You can add `typeof a === 'number'` if you want to exclude strings.

Answer (score 1):

[YourJS](http://yourjs.com) provides the following two functions which work for all numbers including returning `false` for `-Infinity` and `Infinity`:

```
function isFloat(x) {
  return typeOf(x, 'Number') && !!(x % 1);
}

function isInt(x) {
  return typeOf(x, 'Number') && x % 1 == 0;
}
```

Due to the fact that `typeOf()` is a YourJS internal function, if you wanted to use these definitions you can download the version for just these functions here:  http://yourjs.com/snippets/build/34

Answer (score 1):

Some times Number objects don't allow you to use direct the mod operator (%), if you are facing that case you can use this solution.

```
if(object instanceof Number ){
   if( ((Number) object).doubleValue() % 1 == 0 ){
      //your object is an integer
   }
   else{
      //your object is a double
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one
function amountcheck()
    {
        var dpamt=$('#dpamt').val()/5000;
        var ints=dpamt.toString();
        var isint=ints.split('.');
        if(isint[1]>0)
        {
            alert('float value');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {   
            alert('int value');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Number.isInteger()` method to check if the number is an integer or a float by dividing them for example:

```
    function isNumberFloatOrInteger(a, b){
     if(Number.isInteger(a / b)){
      return true;
      }
      else{ return false };
}
```

Note: `isInteger()` is not compatible with internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

There is Number.isInteger(number) to check this. Doesn't work in Internet Explorer but that browser isn't used anymore. If you need string like "90" to be an integer (which wasnt the question) try Number.isInteger(Number(number)).
The "official" isInteger considers 9.0 as an integer, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number.
It looks like most answers are correct for older browsers but modern browsers have moved on and actually support float integer check.

Answer (score 1):

For Float

```
var decimal=  /^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/; 

if (!price.match(decimal)) {
      alert('Please enter valid float');
      return false;
    }
```

For integer

```
var number = /^\d+$/; 

if (!price.match(number)) {
      alert('Please enter valid integer');
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With this you can check if a string or a number is "decimal" (float properly):

```
var IsDecimal = function(num){
    return ((num.toString().split('.').length) <= 2 && num.toString().match(/^[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?$/)) ? (!isNaN(Number.parseFloat(num))) : false ;
}
```

and this other works for check if a string or a number is Integer:

```
var IsInteger = function(num){
    return ((num.toString().split('.').length) == 1 && num.toString().match(/^[\-]?\d+$/)) ? (!isNaN(Number.parseInt(num))) : false ;
}
```

```js
var IsDecimal = function(num){
    return ((num.toString().split('.').length) <= 2 && num.toString().match(/^[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?$/)) ? (!isNaN(Number.parseFloat(num))) : false ;
}

var IsInteger = function(num){
    return ((num.toString().split('.').length) == 1 && num.toString().match(/^[\-]?\d+$/)) ? (!isNaN(Number.parseInt(num))) : false ;
}


console.log("-------------- As string --------------");
console.log("Integers:");
console.log("0 = " + IsInteger("0"));
console.log("34 = " + IsInteger("34"));
console.log(".34 = " + IsInteger(".34"));
console.log("3.4 = " + IsInteger("3.4"));
console.log("3e = " + IsInteger("3e"));
console.log("e3 = " + IsInteger("e3"));
console.log("-34 = " + IsInteger("-34"));
console.log("--34 = " + IsInteger("--34"));
console.log("034 = " + IsInteger("034"));
console.log("0-34 = " + IsInteger("0-34"));
console.log("Floats/decimals:");
console.log("0 = " + IsDecimal("0"));
console.log("64 = " + IsDecimal("64"));
console.log(".64 = " + IsDecimal(".64"));
console.log("6.4 = " + IsDecimal("6.4"));
console.log("6e2 = " + IsDecimal("6e2"));
console.log("6e = " + IsDecimal("6e"));
console.log("e6 = " + IsDecimal("e6"));
console.log("-64 = " + IsDecimal("-64"));
console.log("--64 = " + IsDecimal("--64"));
console.log("064 = " + IsDecimal("064"));
console.log("0-64 = " + IsDecimal("0-64"));
console.log("\n-------------- As numbers --------------");
console.log("Integers:");
console.log("0 = " + IsInteger(0));
console.log("34 = " + IsInteger(34));
console.log(".34 = " + IsInteger(0.34));
console.log("3.4 = " + IsInteger(3.4));
console.log("-34 = " + IsInteger(-34));
console.log("034 = " + IsInteger(034));
console.log("0-34 = " + IsInteger(0-34));
console.log("Floats/decimals:");
console.log("0 = " + IsDecimal(0));
console.log("64 = " + IsDecimal(64));
console.log(".64 = " + IsDecimal(0.64));
console.log("6.4 = " + IsDecimal(6.4));
console.log("6e2 = " + IsDecimal(6e2));
console.log("-64 = " + IsDecimal(-64));
console.log("064 = " + IsDecimal(064));
console.log("0-64 = " + IsDecimal(0-64));
```

Answer (score 1):

to check the number is Int or not and apply 2 decimal format, you can use the formula below in React-Native.

```
isInt = (n) => {
        return n % 1 === 0;
     }

    show = (x) => {
        if(x) {
           if (this.isInt(x)) {
               return ${x} 
           }
           else {
            return ${x.toFixed(2)}
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but here is my version

```
isInteger: obj => Number.isInteger(!isNaN(obj % 1) && obj % 1 !== 0 ? obj : parseInt(obj)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on all that I have seen here, I've created my own set of functions to test for what I need:

```
function NumberValidator() {
this.isFloat = function (n) {
    return typeof(n)==="number" && n === +n && Math.round(n) !== n;
};

this.isInteger = function (n) {
    return typeof(n)==="number" && n === +n && Math.round(n) === n;
};

this.isFloatOrInteger = function (n) {
    return this.isFloat(n) || this.isInteger(n);
};

this.isNonZeroFloatOrInteger = function (n) {
    return this.isFloatOrInteger(n) && n > 0;
};

this.isNonZeroInteger = function (n) {
    return this.isInteger(n) && n > 0;
};
}
```

However, [shime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726020/shime)'s solution is shorter and with less checks, so it might be a better one.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe isn't as performant as the % answer, which prevents you from having to convert to a string first, but I haven't seen anyone post it yet, so here's another option that should work fine:

```
function isInteger(num) {
    return num.toString().indexOf('.') === -1;
}
```

Comment: Good approach IMHO

Comment: I would add that the ES6 method includes() makes this answer even simpler

Answer (score 0):

This is mine:

```
function isInt(quale) {
    var valore = $('#'+quale).val().toLowerCase();
    if (isNaN(Number(String(valore))) || (valore.indexOf("e") > 0)) {
        // Not int
    } else {
        // Is Int!
    }
}
```

And this:

```
function isFloat(quale) {
   var valore = $('#'+quale).val();
   valore = valore.replace(",", "");
   if (isNaN(String(valore)) || (valore.indexOf("e") > 0)) {
    // Not Float
   } else {
    // Float
   }
}
```

Ad majora!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code.  It checks to make sure it's not an empty string (which will otherwise pass) and then converts it to numeric format.  Now, depending on whether you want '1.1' to be equal to 1.1, this may or may not be what you're looking for.

```
var isFloat = function(n) {
    n = n.length > 0 ? Number(n) : false;
    return (n === parseFloat(n));
};
var isInteger = function(n) {
    n = n.length > 0 ? Number(n) : false;
    return (n === parseInt(n));
};

var isNumeric = function(n){

   if(isInteger(n) || isFloat(n)){
        return true;
   }
   return false;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Condtion for floating validation :**

```
if (lnk.value == +lnk.value && lnk.value != (lnk.value | 0))
```

**Condtion for Integer validation :**

```
if (lnk.value == +lnk.value && lnk.value == (lnk.value | 0))
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The functions below guard against empty strings,undefines,nulls, and max/min value ranges. The Javascript engine should have built in these functions from day one. :)

Enjoy!

```
function IsInteger(iVal) {
    var iParsedVal; //our internal converted int value


    iParsedVal = parseInt(iVal,10);

    if (isNaN(iParsedVal) || Infinity == iParsedVal || -Infinity == iParsedVal) //sanity check - guard against empty strings and max/min values
        return false;
    else
        return Number(iVal) === (iParsedVal | 0); //the 2nd operand group (intValue | 0), evaluates to true only if the intValue is an integer; so an int type will only return true
}

function IsFloat(fVal) {
    var fParsedVal; //our internal converted float value


    fParsedVal = parseFloat(fVal);

    if (isNaN(fParsedVal) || Infinity == fParsedVal || -Infinity == fParsedVal) //sanity check - guard against empty strings and max/min values
        return false;
    else
        return !!(fVal % 1); //true only if there is a fractional value after the mod op; the !! returns the opposite value of the op which reflects the function's return value
}
```

Comment: isFloat(1.0)
=> false

Answer (score 0):

I needed to check an input value if it's integer or float and to do that I've come up with the following:

```js
function isInteger(x) {
  var integer = parseInt(x, 10);
  if (!isNaN(integer) && !isFloat(x)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isFloat(x) {
  var f = parseFloat(x);
  var floor = Math.floor(f);
  var fraction = f - floor;
  if (fraction > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var cases = [
  "1",
  "1.00",
  "1.01",
  "0.05",
  "ab1",
  "ab1.1",
  1,
  1.00,
  1.01,
  0.05,
  1e+5,
  "",
  true,
  false,
  null,
  NaN,
  undefined,
];

console.log("isInteger()");
for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
  console.log(cases[i], isInteger(cases[i]));
}

console.log("\nisFloat()");
for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
  console.log(cases[i], isFloat(cases[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this the most elegant way:

```
function isInteger(n) {
    return n === (n^0);
}
```

It cares also to return false in case of a non-numeric value.

Comment: dude, "Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits", your function can not handling big number

Answer (score 0):

I know there are 30 answers already, but one complicated way is to do this:

```js
function isInteger(n) {
    return n.toString().split('.').length === 1;
}
```

Explanation: We first convert `n` to a string, and split it based on a dot. If `n` is a floating point, like `4.5`, then split will return an array `['4', '5']`. If it is an integer like `45`, it will return `['45']`. Therefore, if the length of the array is 1, then we know it is a number.

P.S. If you want to write this function in the new ES6 format (arrow functions):

```js
const isInteger = n => n.toString().split('.').length === 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I can come up for float and interger number checking.

```js
function isFloat(n) {
  if (!n) {
    return false
  }
  return !isNaN(n % 1) && n % 1 !== 0;
}

function isInt(n) {
  if (n.length==0) {
    return false
  }
  return !isNaN(n % 1) && n % 1 == 0;
}
```

Comment: This claims that `0` is not an integer.

Comment: I updated an integer null condition. it will not return false on zero now. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

A nifty solution is to update the `Number` prototype rather than creating a function, like this:

```js
Number.prototype.integer = function() {
  return this % 1 === 0
}

Number.prototype.float = function() {
  return this % 1 !== 0
}
```

You can now call these methods on any numeric variables rather than passing the variables into functions.

```js
let integerTest = 1
let floatTest = 0.5

integerTest.integer() // true
integerTest.float() // false

floatTest.integer() // false
floatTest.float() // true
```

Mostly just a style preference but I like it!

Answer (score -2):

```
parseInt(yourNumber)=== parseFloat(yourNumber)
```