# What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?

Tags: javascript

If unary `+`/`-` operators are used to perform conversions as the `Number()` casting function, then why do we need unary operators? What's the special need of these unary operators?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The Unary `+` operator converts its operand to Number type.
The Unary `-` operator converts its operand to Number type, and then negates it.
(per the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf))

In practice, Unary `-` is used for simply putting negative numbers in normal expressions, e.g.:

```
var x = y * -2.0;
```

That's the unary minus operator at work. The Unary `+` is equivalent to the Number() constructor called as a function, as implied by the spec.

I can only speculate on the history, but the unary +/- operators behave similarly in many C-derived languages. I suspect the Number() behavior is the addition to the language here.

Answer (score 1):

The practical side of this is if you have a function that you need to return a number you can use

```
const result = +yourFunc()
```

instead of

```
const result = Number(yourFunc())
```

or

```
const result = -yourFunc()
```

instead of

```
const result = -Number(yourFunc())
```

It will return NaN the same way that Number().

IMO makes things a little harder to read, but could be useful to keep your lines short?