# Javascript + operator

Tags: javascript

What is the application of the plus operator in these cases? I have seen it used in these ways but don't see how it operates.

```
start = +new Date;

+array[i]

+f.call(array, array[i], i)

x = +y
```

Comment: One more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330499/operator-before-expression-in-javascript-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`+` will implicitly *cast* a string / boolean value into a `Number()`.

```
+"66" === 66
```

---

If the string cannot be converted into a `Number`, the value will be `NaN`

```
+"not possible" // evaluates to NaN
```

---

In the case of a `Date()` object, `+` will also *cast* the data into its numerical representation, that is the *UNIX timestamp*.

So, finally spoken, leading an *expression* with `+` is pretty much the same as explicitly wrapping the `Number()` constructor around it:

```
+new Date()
```

equals

```
Number( new Date() )
```

Comment: or any primitive value into a number for that matter...