# What is the code " length === +length" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just read the underscope source code, and cannot get the point from this code:

```
_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return obj;
    iterator = createCallback(iterator, context);
    var i, length = obj.length;
    if (length === +length) {   // why +length?
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            iterator(obj[i], i, obj);
        }
    } else {
        var keys = _.keys(obj);
        for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
            iterator(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

why length===+length ? I guess this used for force to convert if length is not a number?
Could somebody give me a hand?

Comment: There was an exact duplicate, it's even related to the exact same code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330499/operator-before-expression-in-javascript-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+length is a method to convert anything to a number.

If it's a number, the value doesn't change, and the comparison returns true.
If it's not a number, the assertion is false.

[What is unary + used for in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`+length` converts any value of length to a number (NaN if not possible).

So `length===+length` just tests that `length` is really a number (not a string that could be converted to a number), and that it's not NaN (which isn't equal to itself).