# issue with comparing two numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

my html code is like:

```
<html>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">   
function fun()
{
var l = document.test.low.value;
var h = document.test.high.value;
alert(l);
alert(h);
    if(l >h){
        alert("low greater than high low is -"+l+"high is -"+h);
    }
}
</SCRIPT>

<body>

<form name="test">
<input type="text" size="11" id="low" />
<input type="text" size="11" id="high" />
<input type="button" value="sss" onClick="fun()"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i compare this two values using low is 12 and high is 112 is not working.
like 22 and 122, 33 and 133 etc....

I am using IE browser version 8. please help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Convert the values to numbers:

```js
if(Number(l) > Number(h)){ /* … */ }
```

or alternatively, parse each string as a float:

```js
if(Number.parseFloat(l) > Number.parseFloat(h)){ /* … */ }
```

or as an integer:

```js
if(Number.parseInt(l, 10) > Number.parseInt(h, 10)){ /* … */ }
```

Comment: It will not work if number happens to be octal format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: yes you are right then in that case:use base value or simply use Number()

Comment: idk what the reason is but the Number() did not worked for me , but other stuff works

Answer (score 11):

You need to convert them to numbers:

```
if(+l > +h){
```

The unary plus operator will convert the string value to numeric value. See this question for more details:
[What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/RZJ5m/).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ***with base*** to get correct results:

```
var l = parseInt(document.test.low.value, 10);
var h = parseInt(document.test.high.value, 10);
```

Comment: Not sure `parseInt` is good here, for example `10a` will be converted to `10` even though it's not really a number - using the unary plus will make it `NaN` value which is more proper IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: In that case `+` can be prefixed and then `parseInt` but using `+` alone won't avoid octal number problem AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lnum = new Number(l);
var hnmu = new Number(h);
if(lnum > hnum){
alert('if');

}else{
alert('else');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two strings in an if statement:

```
if ( l > h) {}    
when l = "12" and h = "112"
```

It compares these two values as strings as `"3" > "1"`. It says `l > h` is **true**