# IF Greater not working well in js

Tags: jquery

I have 2 numeric input fields and the below runs when the user stops inputting. What I am doing is checking that input a number is not bigger than input b and if it is show error.

The issue is that calculation is not happening well. For instance it works if a is 200 and b is 100 but not if a is 200 and b is 5

Not sure why... so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$("#input_6_23, #input_6_24").on({  
  blur: function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("input_6_23").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("input_6_24").value;

        if(a > b) {     
            alert(a is bigger than b);          
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [issue with comparing two numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094299/issue-with-comparing-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its working so?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#input_6_23, #input_6_24").on('blur',function() {

      check();
    });
    function check(){
       var a = Number($("#input_6_23").val());
       var b = Number($("#input_6_24").val());

       if(a > b) {     
        alert(a+' is bigger than '+b);          
       } else {
        alert("error");
    }  
}});
```

Comment: Yes mate worked like a charm. Sorry for the late reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Change into:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_6_23").value, 10);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_6_24").value, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing string comparisons, not numeric comparison.  You can convert to a number before comparing like this (note the addition of `+` signs when retrieving the `.value`):

```
$("#input_6_23, #input_6_24").on({  
  blur: function() {
        var a = +document.getElementById("input_6_23").value;
        var b = +document.getElementById("input_6_24").value;

        if(a > b) {     
            alert("a is bigger than b");          
        }
  }
});
```

P.S. You also have to make your `a is bigger than b` into a valid string with quotes around it.

There are multiple ways to convert a string to a number:

```
var num = parseInt(str, 10);
var num = +str;
var num = Number(str);
```

---

And, hopefully this is just for testing because putting an `alert()` on a `blur` event is pretty obnoxious in an actual real use scenario.