# Javascript if else condition using greater than >

Tags: javascript

I have problem in if else condition

First,

`amt` has value of 1000.
`actualamt` has value of 500.

I am receiving the above values from text boxes.

My condition is if actualamt is greater than amt, it will not proceed.
But even if the value of actualamt is lower than amt, it didnt accept.

here's my code

```
if (actualamt > amt) {
  checker = 0;
  $.toast({
    heading: 'Note:',
    text: "You have exceeded amsount for settle. Please check the amount.",
    icon: 'info',
    loader: false,
    stack: false,
    position: 'top-center',
    bgColor: '#FFA500',
    textColor: 'white',
    allowToastClose: false,
    hideAfter: 4000
  });
}
```

Can you help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Are those variables actually integer values or are they strings? Moreover, your if condition does exactly the opposite of what you are saying--> It will proceed if actualamt is greater than amt

Comment: do you have strings as value?

Comment: I'm getting the value from a textbox

Comment: Five hundred is **LESS THAN** one thousand!

Comment: `if (parseInt(actualamt) > parseInt(amt) ){` Change your condition by this,

Comment: change the text box from `input type = text` to `input type = number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript string/integer comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons) and [issue with comparing two numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094299) and [javascript if number greater than number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079626) and [IF Greater not working well in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967730)

Comment: Using parseInt works! Thanks guys for helping me, especially @harishsharma.

Comment: @harishsharma — Never use parseInt without a radix argument.

Comment: This post is leading towards parseInt vs unary plus argument. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/1955268) for more details on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For comparing numerical values, you could convert the strings to a number with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus). This does not hurt, if you have already numbers.

```
if (+actualamt > +amt) {
```

Comment: @YosvelQuintero, it looks like some people follows a herd behaviour and sometimes need a more complicated result as js offers, like `+` vs `parseFloat`/`parseInt`. as long as this language offers this operands with the implicit type conversion, i take this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response.. Learning with this QA [parseInt vs unary plus - when to use which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which/17106702#17106702) ;)