# How sort a table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

Hi I want sort my Persian table with JavaScript when click on header. I use the w3school example. it is work correctly in English but in Persian some character not compute (گچ پژ) for sorting. also the number is incorrect and for example Instead of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11), it returns(1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).
how can I fix this?
the code I use is:

```js
        function sortTable(n) {
            
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            switching = true;
            //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
            dir = "asc";
            /*Make a loop that will continue until
            no switching has been done:*/
            while (switching) {
                //start by saying: no switching is done:
                switching = false;
                rows = table.rows;
                
                /*Loop through all table rows (except the
                first, which contains table headers):*/
                for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                    //start by saying there should be no switching:
                    shouldSwitch = false;
                    /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
                    one from current row and one from the next:*/
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                    /*check if the two rows should switch place,
                    based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
                    if (dir == "asc") {
                        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (dir == "desc") {
                        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                    and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                    switching = true;
                    //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                    switchcount++;
                } else {
                    /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
                    set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
                    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <table class="table table-light table-striped border table-hover text-center w-100" id="myTable">
        <thead class="table thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(0)"><i class="bi bi-sort-down"></i>ردیف</th>
                <th style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(1)">نام<i class="bi bi-sort-down"></i></th>
                <th style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(2)">فامیل<i class="bi bi-sort-down"></i></th>
                <th style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(3)"><i class="bi bi-sort-down"></i>ایمیل</th>
                <th style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(4)"><i class="bi bi-sort-down"></i>نوع کاربری</th>
              
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>صادق</td>
                <td>شجاعی فرد</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
                <td>ادمین</td>
      
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>سعید</td>
                <td>شجاعی فرد</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                <td>ادمین</td>
       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>حسین</td>
                <td>مرادی</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
         
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>مریم</td>
                <td>آرش</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
         
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>پویان</td>
                <td>جزینی</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>آرش</td>
                <td>ابراهمی</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
      
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>حامد</td>
                <td>امیر خسرو</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
           
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>جواد</td>
                <td>گودرزی</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>یوسف</td>
                <td>معمار</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
             
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>ژاله</td>
                <td>ژاله ای</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>عادی</td>
 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you add HTML so the problem is reproducible. Better still, can you insert a runnable snippet (using toolbar), so that when we run it we can see the sorting problem?

Comment: i add it my code with sample data

Comment: OK, Can you explain in detail where it goes wrong with the Persian? Most of us here don't know Persian, and wouldn't know what is wrong.

Comment: The wrong arrangement of numbers is obvious i want the number sort as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 not 1,10,11,2,20,21,3,4,5,... ; And for the character for example in the 3rd column (ژاله) should be in the 5 row not 9 for the ascending sorting. and "گودرزی" should be in 7 row.

Comment: Yes the number sorting problem is obvious and has been [answered several times before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094299/issue-with-comparing-two-numbers-in-javascript). I would focus your question on the issue with the Persian sorting only. Thanks for adding what is the expected sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why the sorting does not work properly is because you sort it as string. The solution is to convert the string to number so the sorting behaviour works as expected.

Below is the change point inside `while` loop.

```js
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n].innerHTML;
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[n].innerHTML;
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
            based on the direction, asc or desc:*/

      let first = 0;
      let second = 0;

      if (n === 0) {
        first = parseInt(x);
        second = parseInt(y);
      } else {
        first = x.localeCompare(y, "fa");
      }

      if (
        (dir == "asc" && first > second) ||
        (dir == "desc" && first < second)
      ) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
      continue;
    }
    /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
            set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
      dir = "desc";
      switching = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The Persian texts are not numbers

Comment: thank you. the number sorting is correct in your code but for the Persian character is still wrong. Even more wrong than before.

Comment: I just fixed the code because I didn't  aware that you also want to sort by other column. Could you please check if the latest snippet work as expected?

Comment: I copy this for in my project and only the number column sort correctly.

Comment: The sort by email works as expected on my side (4th column from the left), though I cannot really confirm how the result looks like on Persian columns

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd is still wrong.

Comment: I don't know much about Persian, but probably you need a [Locale Compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: You can also check out [Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator)

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina thank you for the suggestion. The `localeCompare()` method seems to do the job. Though, we still need @link to confirm the sorting result.

Comment: glad that it works. I just refactored the code to make it more concise and easier to read.