# What does "i = +i" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery source:

```
eq: function( i ) {
    i = +i;
    return i === -1 ?
        this.slice( i ) :
        this.slice( i, i + 1 );
},
```

Is it used for make sure parse i to int?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators

Comment: @scibuff: `var i = -5; i = +i; console.log(i);`.... still negative (basic math).

Comment: @scibuff: How so? The first few words of that question are the answer to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it used for make sure parse i to int?

No, it is to make sure that `i` is a **number** (either `float` or `int`). Given what the function is doing, it was better to convert `i` to an non-decimal value though, I'm not sure how `slice` handles decimals.

More information: [`MDN - Arithmetic Operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29)

Comment: `slice` converts its arguments via the [ToInteger](http://es5.github.com/#x9.4) operation. (Basically, if handed a fractional numbers, it floors them.)

Answer (score 3):

Almost, but *any* number is fine.

> `[ECMA-262: 11.4.6]:` The unary `+` operator converts its operand to `Number` type.
>
> The production *UnaryExpression : + UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Return ToNumber(GetValue(*expr*)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will make sure it is int (or a number in general as @Felix says). Try this code out:

```
var i = "2";
console.log(i === 2); // false
console.log(+i === 2); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, applying the unary `+` to a variable ensures that if it's some other type (a string, for instance), it gets [converted to a number](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) (not an int, JavaScript doesn't have ints although it uses them internally for some operations). The number can be fractional, and if it's a string it's parsed in the usual way JavaScript parses numbers (so for instance, `+"0x10"` is `16` decimal).

Answer (score 0):

> `+i` makes sure that i is parsed into an number.

Comment: Wrong. `i+=i` increments the actual value +1! **NOT** `i=+i` -- http://www.devcurry.com/2011/07/unary-plus-operator-in-javascript.html

Comment: I had an syntax error. I deleted this as it also was not useful for the question.

Comment: @Smamatti:- i think you should check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators

Comment: Just did a quick test in chrome. It works like parseFloat for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: @Pranav I don't see how this is related to the meaning of the incremental operator `+=` which **EvilP** used earlier. -- As you can see in the comment above, he edited his post due to this syntax error.

Comment: @Smamatti: Actually i did not look properly when i was writing comment.My Mistake...