# How is an array reference into an empty string + true a valid character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure what is happening in this line of javascript:

```
alert( (''+[][[]])[!+[]+!+[]] ); // shows "d"
```

What I've figured out:

```
var a = ! + []; // == true
var b = ! + [] + ! + []; // == 2
```

It seems that the second part is a reference into an array of letters or some sort, but I don't understand how that is coming from

```
(''+[][[]])
```

Also:

```
alert( (''+[][])[2] ); // nothing happens; console says "unexpected token ]"
alert( (''+[[]][])[2] ); // nothing happens; console says "unexpected token ]"
alert( (''+[[]][[]])[2] ); // shows "d"
alert( (""+true)[2] ); // shows "u"
```

Comment: Now that's a real question...

Comment: See also: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Also of interest: http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html

Comment: Someone wrote a tool to convert javascript to '[]{}()+!' characters: http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll decompose it for you:

```
  ('' + [][[]])[!+[]+!+[]]
= ('' + undefined)[!+[]+!+[]]  // [][[]] grabs the []th index of an empty array.
= 'undefined'[! + [] + ! + []]
= 'undefined'[(! + []) + (! + [])]
= 'undefined'[true + true]
= 'undefined'[2]
= 'd'
```

`! + [] == true` is explained here [What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)

Answer (score 2):

Because `"" + true` is the string `"true"`, and the third character (index 2) is `u`.

Things like `! + []` work because `+` can also be a unary operator, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators).

Comment: and the `d` is the 3rd char of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( (""+true)[2] ); // shows "u"
```

It's returning the 3rd letter of the string "true".

What does this return?

```
alert( (''+[[]][[]]));
```