# what is the code return val + '' === numVal + '' for?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book and saw a function, but I could not understand the lines **var numVal = +val; return val + '' === numVal + '';**. Can anyone help explaining it a bit? Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

function isNumeric(val) {
    var numVal = +val;  // what's this for?
    return val + '' === numVal + ''; // what's this for?
}

function filterNumeric(arr) {
    var result = [];

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var val  = arr[i];
        if (isNumeric(val)) {
            result.push(val);
        }
  }

  return result;
}


var arr = ["a",1, 2, "b"];

arr = filterNumeric(arr);
alert(arr);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var numVal = +val;
```

When `val` is a string, `numVal` will be the string converted to a number. (similar to `parseInt()`, without the radix magic)

```
 val + '' === numVal + '';
```

This uses the identity operator `===` and checks if the string value(created by adding an empty string) of `val` and `numval` are the same. Basically, if `numVal` was `NaN`, it would evaluate to `false`. There really isn't any need for `===` here, `==` would have sufficed for the same operation.

Answer (score 2):

These are JavaScript tricks which essentially do type-casting (coercing).

- The `+val` is the numeric unary `+` operator applied to `val`, which forces it to be interpreted as a number. If it helps, in English I always think of this as meaning "positive `val`" (not to be confused with absolute value). See also [What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators).
- The `val + ''` is the binary `+` operator applied to two objects `val` and the string `''`. Namely, this is the string concatenation operator. This forces `val` to be interpreted as a string and then concatenated with the empty string (which does nothing). The same thing is done to `numVal`.
- The `===` is the "strictly-equal" equality operator which tests both value *and type*. Note this is parsed as `(val + '') === (numVal + '')`. Since in this case you will always be comparing two strings, this is not really necessary; `==` would suffice.

---

The code is equivalent to the following psudocode:

```
//var numVal = +val
var numVal = numeric.Parse(val) or NaN;

//return val + '' === numVal + ''
return val.ToString().Equals(numVal.ToString());
```

---

Looking at some examples:

```
val     numVal   (val + '')   (numVal + '')   return
------------------------------------------------------
23      23       '23'         '23'            true
'23'    23       '23'         '23'            true
'23x'   NaN      '23x'        'NaN'           false
'junk'  NaN      'junk'       'NaN'           false
'1E23'  1e+23    '1E23'       '1e+23'         false
'1e+23' 1e+23    '1e+23'      '1e+23'         true
1e+23   1e+23    '1e+23'      '1e+23'         true
```

Answer (score 1):

The code actually is :

```
 return (val + '') === (numVal + '') ;
```

which translates to `A === B` i.e. is A strictly equal to B , having same datatype and value.
Here `val` and `numVal` are two integers ,by adding `''` to them, they result gets typecasted into a string.

The statement compares two numeric strings, and returns `true` or `false` based on whether they are equal or not.

eg;

```
'1' === 1     // false
'1' == 1 // true
1 + ''   === '1'  // true
2 + '' ===  (1+1) + ''   // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` has a lot of meanings in Javascript. The first unary `+` works for numerical values. The second & third is catenating with the empty string to get a string representation of the number