# What does +obj.length mean in Underscore.js’s each method?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to read underscore.js. I’m going through the `var each = _.each = _.forEach` method.

I understand strict equals (`===`), but I do not understand what `+obj.length` means.

```
else if (obj.length === +obj.length)
```

Here is [a link to the code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), and here is the full method:

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
      obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think it ensures that `obj.length` is a number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the significant use of Unary Plus and Minus operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a unary + operator. It converts its argument to a number. Basically that line checks if `obj.length` is a number.