# Sorting an array of divs by their ID values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs that I would like to sort by their ID values. The problem is that the IDs are values like this: "indexNumber123".

I would like to sort them "numerically" as in "indexNumber1","indexNumber2","indexNumber3" to reorder them before displaying their HTML.

The code base for this application is a sloppy mess so I thought I could just get away with doing this via DOM manipulation with jquery and just be done with it.

I tried to do this by getting an array of the divs and then passing a compare function to the sort method of the array. I thought I could parse the ID values in the compare method and compare the numeric values, but this is not sorting them correctly.

```
function compare(a,b) {

    var aId = parseInt(a.id.replace( /^\D+/g, ''));
    var bId = parseInt(b.id.replace( /^\D+/g, ''));

    if (aId < bId)
        return -1;
    if (aId > bId)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

//fired on a button click
function sortNumeric() {
        var arrDivs = [];

        $('[id^="indexNumber"]').each(
            function() {
                arrDivs.push($(this)[0]);
            });

        var sortedDivs = arrDivs.sort(compare);
        console.dir(sortedDivs);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a simple fiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: Please show some example markup for the divs, and how they don't "sort correctly". Also, where are you displaying them? You currently are only sorting the jQuery collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function compare(a,b) {

    var aId = parseInt(a.id.replace( /^\D+/g, ''));
    var bId = parseInt(b.id.replace( /^\D+/g, ''));

    return +aId - +bId
}

//fired on a button click
function sortNumeric() {
        var arrDivs = $('[id^="indexNumber"]'), 
            sortedDivs = arrDivs.sort(compare);

        console.dir(sortedDivs);
}
```

Try this. you probably need to convert "stringID" to NumberID

Comment: YESSSS that works perfectly, but why? Why was my code not working and what exactly is +aId - +bId? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The Unary +/- operator converts its operand to Number type.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators

Comment: So parseInt() wasn't converting it to an int?

Comment: Why not? parseInt will get the same result as the unary+ for integer