# What does the + in this statement do: a = +array[i]

Tags: javascript, d3.js, syntax

I'm looking at the source code of the [sum function of d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/arrays/sum.js) and I'm wondering what the `+` in line 8 and 10 does. It's this statement:

```
a = +array[i]
```

So it's an assignment of the ith element of `array` to `a`, but what does the `+` in front of `array[i]` do? The same syntax is repeated in line 10, where the `+` precedes the function call. I have never seen such a syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: Look up *unary plus*. It effectively causes [ToNumber] to be applied to the operand.

Comment: In JavaScript + will convert string into numeric value.Okay

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the significant use of Unary Plus and Minus operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)

Answer (score 1):

What you're really doing is applying the operator `+` to the element at index `i` in the array. And what does that operator do? Basically, it's a shorthand way of forcibly turning a variable into a number. As an example, run the following code:

```
+new Date()
```

Instead of a date object, you'll get an integer representation of the date.