# What does mean n=+Number || 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found in HighStock js they have write a syntax like

```
n= +Number || 0
```

can anyone please expalin mean what does it mean?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is:

```
n= +Number || 0;
```

variable `n` will be assigned a value which should be `typeof == number`. If number is string then `+number` will be a shorthand to convert string number values to number.

So if value comes as `"20"`, its a String value and if you prefix it with `+` sign then it will be converted to an Integer like `20`.

Here:

```
n= +Number || 0;
```

`Integer 0` will be assigned if there is no value in the var `Number`/or undefined.

```js
var number = "20", nonumber;

var n = +number || 0;

$('p:eq(0)').text(n);

var o = +nonumber || 0;

$('p:eq(1)').text(o);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: The unary `+` does not "convert to integer".

Comment: @user2864740 can't get you.

Comment: Example: `+'1.23'` The unary plus on strings is "sort of" like `parseFloat`, but it differs.

Comment: @user2864740 okay i got you.

Comment: @user2864740 i think it just converts the string number values to numbers regardless of checking int/float. i think.

Answer (score 2):

It means if `Number` variable is `not defined` or `its not numeric` then assign `0` to the `n` variable.

*Example*

```
Example 1>
var Number = 'test';
n= +Number || 0;

O/P:
n = 0
--------------------------------------------
Example 2>
var Number = 2;
n= +Number || 0;

O/P:
n = 2
--------------------------------------------
Example 3>
n= +Number || 0;

O/P:
n = 0
```

Comment: what is meaning of `+` before Number?

Comment: It checks whether its number( numeric value ) or not

Comment: You're wrong. If `Number = '2'` Then value of `n` will be `2`. Even when Number is string, it can be converted to Number type by `+`.

Comment: That's what I said dude

Comment: @MangeshParte Read you're first statement. `if Number variable is not defined or its not numeric then assign 0 to the n variable.`

Comment: Small example: `var Number = 'test';` in this statement `Number` variable is defined but its not numeric so value of `n` will be 0. Is as simple as that

Comment: So the meaning of my line is Even if your variable is  defined it should contain numeric value ( which can be in string format )

Comment: And it's not `you're` it's `your` . `you're` and `your` both has very different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially, when you have either `+` or `-` before a variable, (ie. `+Number`), the variable gets cast to the type *number*. So either this is successful and a number is the output, or the casting fails and `NaN` is returned (**N**ot **a** **N**umber).

Since in most browsers `Number` refers to the object constructor for the type *number*, then the casting of it to a numerical value is not defined, and thus the result is `NaN`, which JavaScript interprets as a false value. Therefore:

```
+Number || 0 == NaN || 0 == 0
```

Unless Number has been defined locally and is a number (or can be casted into a number).

The following describes how each type gets casted into a number:

```
// Strings
+"1.12345" = 1.12345
parseFloat("1.12345") // Equivalent to

// Boolean
+True = 1
+False = 0
Number(True) // Equivalent

// Array
+[1] = NaN
// Casting fails

// Object
+{1:1} = NaN
// Casting Fails

// Undefined
+undefined = NaN
// Casting Fails

// Null
+null = 0
Number(null) // Equivalent

// Hex encoded number
+0x00FF = 255
parseInt("0x00FF", 16) // Equivalent

// Function
+function(){} = NaN
// Casting Fails
```