# JS: What's the difference between =+ and +=

Tags: javascript, operators, variable-assignment

given the following block of code

```
var sumX = 0,
    sumY = 0,
    x = 1,
    y = 2;
sumX =+ x;
sumY += y;
```

What is the difference between the two assignment operators?

Comment: Please use the search: [`[javascript] "=+"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%3D%2B%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=+` will cast implicitly `x` to a number and assign `sumX` the value

`+=` will add `x` to `sumX` without an attempt at casting

Answer (score 1):

- `sumY += y;` adds `y` to `sumY`.
- `sumY =+ y;` is equivalent to `sumY = (+y);`. For numbers, the [unary plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators) is a no-op, so the entire expression simply assigns `y` to `sumY`.