# Js object key: plus value syntax

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found this weird syntax in [d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084)

```
var heatmapChart = function(tsvFile) {
    d3.tsv(tsvFile,
    function(d) {
      return {
        day: +d.day,
        hour: +d.hour,
        value: +d.value
      };
    },
```

What plus in

```
      day: +d.day,
```

mean?

Comment: @Bergi it's not a duplicate at all.

Comment: How so? Doesn't the duplicate explain what `+` does in front of a value? Or are you asking about something else?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5450076/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a unary conversion. It's a shorthand method to convert to a number. From the [ECMAScript docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6):

> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.
>
> The production UnaryExpression : + UnaryExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
>
> Return ToNumber(GetValue(expr)).

```
var a = "45"; //typeof String
a = +a; // now typeof Number
```

Comment: Unary plus has nothing to do with concatenation or adding?

Comment: Well damn, you're right.

Comment: omg I am really close to giving up with Javascript... Thank you