# Java script convert string to number

Tags: javascript, string, variables, operators

why java script convert string to number when I'am put only + before string

```
var x = "44";
var y =(+x); 
var z = 34 + x;  
console.log(typeof y); //number
console.log(typeof z); //string
```

Comment: That's what the unary `+` operator is supposed to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators:

`+` is the Unary operator. It attempts to convert the operand to a number, if it is not already.