# What does the + operator mean in this example?

Tags: javascript

I often see the `+` operator in examples like this. I don't quite understand what plus means here?

```
const contentLength = +response.headers.get('Content-Length');
```

I am studying the fetch-progress topic, and I don’t understand the `+` in the line I indicated.

Comment: Shorthand to convert the value to a numeric type using `Number()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69470467/519413

Comment: Things like this can be tested in the browser console or Node REPL. Type in something like `+ "1234"` and see what comes back.