# How can I check to see if a value is a float in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, typeof

I want to check to see if my input is a float.

Sooo something like...

```
if (typeof (input) == "float")
do something....
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3885817/239241

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> The **parseFloat()** function parses an argument (*converting it to a
>   string first if needed*) and returns a floating point number.

```
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(input))) {
    // is float    
}
```

Comment: what if I pass integer instead of float in input?

Comment: `!Number.isInteger(val)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger or see the “already has answers here” link at the top of this page

Comment: @MrColes: your comment is wrong on this context. OP has specifically asked how to identify a float. `!Number.isInteger('lorem ipsum')` returns true too. As MDN notes, *The Number.isInteger() method determines whether the passed value is an **integer**.*

Comment: parseFloat("2A") return 2, which is not NaN, so this is not correct.

Comment: @thienDX: 2A is a hexadecimal number. 

MDN notes, *For radices above 10, letters of the English alphabet indicate numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), A through F are used.*

Comment: @naveen it's was not a good example. parseFloat("2Z") also return 2

Answer (score 3):

As spraff said, you can check the type of an input with `typeof`. In this case

```
if (typeof input === "number") {
    // It's a number
}
```

JavaScript just has `Number`, not separate `float` and `integer` types. More about figuring out what things are in JavaScript: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

If it may be something else (like a string) but you want to convert it to a number if possible, you can use either `Number` or `parseFloat`:

```
input = Number(input);
if (!isNaN(input)) {
    // It was already a number or we were able to convert it
}
```

More:

- [`Number` called as a function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.1)
- [`isNaN`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.4)
- [`parseFloat`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.3)

Answer (score 2):

[typeof foo === "number"](http://united-coders.com/matthias-reuter/all-about-types-part-4)

All numbers are floats in Javascript. Note that the type name is in quotes, it's a string, and it's all lower case. Also note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function, no need for parens (though they're harmless).