# How to identify if a number is an integer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

I have been using a JavaScript function `isNaN(value)` for identifying whether a number is an integer or a float. But now I am facing another problem that isNaN() is not filtering float. It is accepting it as integer.

Also it must treat 1.0 as an integer

Can someone guide me to find out a way in which I can filter integer values as well?

Comment: A decimal is a number. Perhaps you mean `integer`?

Comment: +1 to u @tekknolagi Yes I do mean integer

Comment: @OMTheEternity unfortunately comment upvotes get no rep

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Comment: @OMTheEternity see my answer :) enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

In javaScript, there is no difference between decimal and integer, they are both `number`. One way to diffrentiated is to use regular expression to test the transformed string of the number

```
var intTest = /^-?(\d+|0)$/;
if(intTest.test(someNumber)) {
   console.log('int');

}

// intTest.test(2);
// true
// intTest.test(2.1);
// false
// intTest.test(0);
// true
// intTest.test(-1);
// true
// intTest.test(-1.2);
// false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_int(value){ 
  if ((parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)) {
      return true;
  }
  else { 
      return false;
  } 
}
```

this too:

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 == 0;
}
```

This will work if you want `2.00` to count as an integer.

```
function is_int(value){ 
   return !isNaN(parseInt(value * 1));
}
```

Will work if you want strictly of `int` type.

Comment: I say of `int` type, but there is only `number` in JS. You know what I mean.

Comment: The Last Solutions accepts the alphabets.. I need only integers to passthrough

Comment: @OMTheEternity the last solution will not accept strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression

```
if(/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/.test(1.23)) {
    // hurray this is a number
}
```