# Facebook login JS - FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login') triggers without login button click

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

really need your help with log-in-with-facebook feature I'm trying to implement on my website.

Basically, I'm trying to achieve the following:

- if user has acknowledged the app before and clicks FB Log in button
  on my website, they get logged into the website (with website's user
  account associated with the Facebook user ID)
- if user has not acknowledged the app before, on FB log in (and subscription to app) they get redirected to website's registration page. Here the form is pre-filled with user data
  coming through Facebook and registration process becomes easier and faster.

I'm using the code below.

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: 'xxxxxxxx',
          status: true,
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    if ((parseFloat(uid) == parseInt(uid)) && !isNaN(uid)) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/user_actions/prep_facebook_registration',
                            cache: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { 'uid': uid, 'token': accessToken },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data) {
                                if (data.success=='true') {
                                    if ((typeof(data.redirect) != 'undefined')) {
                                        window.location=data.redirect;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
              }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(res) {
                if (!res.authResponse) {
                    window.location='/access/logout';
                }
            });
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            //not doing anything so far
          }
        });
      };
            (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

LogIn button lays further down in a website:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" data-show-faces="false" data-width="166" data-max-rows="1" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 0;" scope="email"></div>
```

The problem here is that FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login') triggers not only on FB log in button click, but also if user has logged to Facebook and only after comes to my website. This causing a redirection to registration page or current page reload even if user hasn't clicked the login button!

'/user_actions/prep_facebook_registration' holds a script, which is checking if the member has to be redirected to registration page or should be loggedin with local account. It returns the URL to redirect.

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login') being triggered outside the login button click?

Comment: if you have resolved this issue, you can post it as an answer ( even to your own question).   you might have to wait a day or two till you are allowed to answer your own question though... happy coding!

Comment: Works well. Thank you for taking the time to write the solution as well. Please post it as the answer and mark it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=====================

**Edit: Ok, I think there's a bit of a progress here :)**

I've extended the FB login button with *onlogin* event which calls a JS function Facebook_login()

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="Facebook_login()" autologoutlink="true" [parameters]></div>
```

I've exported *uid* and *accessToken* variables outside window.fbAsyncInit function so I could access them from anywhere else:

```
var uid;
var accessToken;

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      your parameters
   });
});
```

Then, I got FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login') to only assign values to my *uid* and *accessToken* variables, but not perform any redirection.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  }
});
```

And finally, my custom function Facebook_login () fetches the uid and accessToken values and does the rest of the operation. This time it happens only when login button is clicked. Please note, this function is outside window.fbAsyncInit()

```
function Facebook_login () {
          if ((parseFloat(uid) == parseInt(uid)) && !isNaN(uid)) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/user_actions/prep_facebook_registration',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 'uid': uid, 'token': accessToken },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.success=='true') {
                            if ((typeof(data.redirect) != 'undefined')) {
                                if (data.redirect=='current') {
                                    location.reload();
                                } else {
                                    window.location=data.redirect;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
      }
```

This seems to do a job for me. If anyone has any better solutions, your input would be appreciated :)

Comment: This is the solution, you can remove FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login' and get the accessToken by calling FB.getLoginStatus in your Facebook_login function. However, it's bad to add onlogin= on the login button element, but there is no other solutions...

Answer (score 8):

Actualy, there's a better solution.

There are 2 things that you could do better:

1. In your `FB.init` method, you're setting `status: true`. This tells the page that it should check whether the user is logged in the facebook immediately after page loads. In your case, it's not only that you don't need it - it will take some of your visitor's bandwidth for round trip to facebook that you don't actually need.
2. You don't need to remember uid and accessToken variables since you can get them on demand by using `FB.getLoginStatus` method.

The complete solution based on your sample code would be:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status     : false,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

   function Facebook_login () {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            if ((parseFloat(uid) == parseInt(uid)) && !isNaN(uid)) {
               $.ajax({
                   url: '/user_actions/prep_facebook_registration',
                   cache: false,
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: { 'uid': uid, 'token': accessToken },
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(data) {
                      if (data.success=='true') {
                          if ((typeof(data.redirect) != 'undefined')) {
                              if (data.redirect=='current') {
                                  location.reload();
                              } else {
                                  window.location=data.redirect;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                   }
               });
            }
         }
      }
   }
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="Facebook_login()" autologoutlink="true" [parameters]></div>
```

Comment: I like this one. The following code seems not so pretty: "parseFloat(uid) == parseInt(uid)) && !isNaN(uid)"

Comment: Yeah, I don't like it either but since Javascript doesn't come with built-in function to check if some text is integer value, this is the best way to do the check. For example, see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer