# Get auth token by using fb button in .net

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook app is there any way to get user auth token by using Facebook login button i have try many example from Google but not get success. Please provide me a solution with all required code. Basically I want to allow user to fill there uname and pwd of facebook 
and get there auth token to be saved in db which i use in future to get users info.

Here is example but not work

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```
<body>
<p>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" onclick="" value="Authorize in Facebook using hidden iframe!"
        id="iLogin" />
</p>
<iframe id="fbFrame" src="about:blank;" border="0"></iframe>
<p style="color: green; font-size: 30px;" id="fbtoken">
</p>
<p style="color: green; font-size: 30px;" id="fbuid">
</p>
<script>

    var my_client_id = "my_client_id",

        my_redirect_uri = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",

        my_type = "user_agent",
        my_display = "popup"
    authorize_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"

    authorize_url += "client_id=" + my_client_id
    authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + my_redirect_uri,
    authorize_url += "&type=" + my_type,
    authorize_url += "&display=" + my_display,
    authorize_url += "&scope=offline_access"

    setIFrameUrl = function () {
        $("#fbFrame").attr("src", authorize_url);
    }

    getToken = function () {
        debugger;
        var loc = document.getElementById("fbFrame").contentWindow.location.href
        if (/access_token/.test(loc)) {
            var fbToken = loc.match(/access_token=(.*)$/)[1]
            var fbId = loc.match(/-(\d*)%/)[1]
            $("#fbtoken").html("Facebook access token: " + fbToken);
            $("#fbuid").html("Facebook user id: " + fbId);
        } else {
            var grantAccessButton = $("#fbFrame").contents().find("input[name=grant_clicked]");
            if (grantAccessButton) { // if app asks for permissions, grant 'em
                grantAccessButton.click();
            }
            setTimeout(getToken, 1000)
        }
    }

    doTheLogin = function () {
        var emailInput = $("#fbFrame").contents().find("input[name=email]");
        var passInput = $("#fbFrame").contents().find("input[name=pass]");
        var loginButton = $("#fbFrame").contents().find("input[name=login]");
        emailInput.val($("#email").val());
        passInput.val($("#password").val());
        loginButton.click();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setIFrameUrl();
        $("#iLogin").click(function () {
            console.log("iLogin clicked!")
            debugger;
            doTheLogin();
        })
        getToken();
    })
</script>
```

Now I have use following code

[Facebook login JS - FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login') triggers without login button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110519/facebook-login-js-fb-event-subscribeauth-login-triggers-without-login-butt)

but still not able to get accessToken there is a function named Facebook_login() which will get Tocken but it never called is there any another changes I need to do or am I doing wrong implementions. I used code as

```
<script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'appId',
            status: false,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

    function Facebook_login() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                alert(accessToken);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="Facebook_login()" autologoutlink="true" scope="publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages,user_groups">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us any code that you have tried?

Comment: I have add the code please check ..

Comment: Please help me regarding this problem

Answer (score 0):

> i have try many example from Google but not get success

You should not start using the API by trying some obscure examples you googled, but by reading the official docs instead. The code you’ve shown looks weird in so many places and even plain wrong in some – I’m not even gonna go into details.

My suggestion: Start by using the JavaScript SDK method [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to have the user log in; afterwards, use [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to request the info you need.

*(And should you have only very little basic knowledge yet on how to use JavaScript in general – then please work through some tutorials on that beforehand.)*