# JavaScript - validate numeric only and within range

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have an asp form which has a number of fields.  On submit I want to check, using javascript that a tickbox has been selected and that an 'amount' field in within a given range AND has numbers only.  I'm struggling to get it to check all three in one go - at the mometn i have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["Amount"].value;
if (x<5 || x >250)
  {
  alert("Please complete all required fields - Amount you wish to save");
  return false;
  }

else if ( myForm.agreesubmit.checked == false )
  {
  alert ( "You Must Agree To The Terms and Conditions" );
  return false;
  } 

}
</script>
```

At the moment this is two seperate checks for tick box select and range.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: why do you want it all to be in one statement?  You're checking for 2 different things and have 2 different responses.  Seems 2 if statements are appropriate.  And presumably invalid input would have a different expected alert response.  So you should probably have 3 separate checks for 3 responses.

Comment: here are some ideas on number validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326653/javascript-for-float-and-integer-number-validation

Comment: Inside the same function body, you use both `document.forms["myForm"]` and `myForm` to reference the same form element. This is not consistent, and also the robustness varies between those two. You should be consistently using the more reliable form.

Comment: It can be seperate statements, I just cant get it to use them both correctly and for the two checks to take place on the amoutn field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function that can do this:

```
function validate(str, chk, min, max) {
  n = parseFloat(str);
  return (chk && !isNaN(n) && n >= min && n <= max);
}
```

then call it like so:

```
function validateForm()
{
  if(!validate(document.forms["myForm"]["Amount"].value, 
     document.forms["myForm"]["agreesubmit"].checked, 5, 250)) {
    alert("Please complete all required fields - Amount you wish to save");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: as a follow up to this, the amount field will allow commas and fullstops, is there a way I can say dont allow those, so whole numbers only?

Comment: change `parseFloat(str)` to `parseInt(str)`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the isNan(). Tutorial found at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Something like:

```
if (isNaN(x) || x < 5 || x > 250))
{
    alert("Please complete all required fields - Amount you wish to save");
    return false;
}
```

Quick note you might be confused about the or/ands, so notice that the x<5 || x >250 is wrapped in () so that it can be partnered with the and numeric condition. Then, finally the whole if wraps the statements.

Comment: isNaN is the best solution to this that I've ever found

Comment: shouldn't that be `|| isNaN(x)`? Using `&&` would make it only true if it was numeric and not numeric.

Comment: @Dylan "within a given range AND has numbers only"

Comment: `isNaN` checks if it's "not a number". `(x<5 || x >250) && isNaN(x)` will never, ever return true.

Comment: I wanted to edit the code snippet and add this description : Added the missing opening parenthesis just before `x < 5 || x > 250)`.

But I received this error message :
"Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure it has numbers only first, then check the number against a range.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["Amount"].value;
if( String(x).search(/^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/) != -1
&&( x<5 || x >250 ))
  {
  alert("Please complete all required fields - Amount you wish to save");
  return false;
  }

else if ( myForm.agreesubmit.checked == false )
  {
  alert ( "You Must Agree To The Terms and Conditions" );
  return false;
  } 

}
</script>
```

via http://ntt.cc/2008/05/10/over-10-useful-javascript-regular-expression-functions-to-improve-your-web-applications-efficiency.html