# Javascript casts floating point numbers to integers without cause

Tags: javascript, floating-point, parsefloat

I wrote a function that behaves differently depending on the numeric type of it's parameters. Integer or float.

Using some code from this question [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer) it was easy to detect if float or not but then I stumbled upon the case that javascript casts `1.0` to `1` without cause if you call a function using that number.

Example:

```
function dump(a, b) {
 console.log(a, typeof b, b);
}

dump('1', 1);
dump('1.0', 1.0);
dump('1.1', 1.1);
```

Output chrome, firefox, ie, opera and safari all gave the same result:

```
1   number 1
1.0 number 1 "wrong"
1.1 number 1.1
```

I know that javascript only knows the type `number` but that forced cast seems to go way overboard. The only solution I came up with was to call the function using string values like `'1.0'`, detect the dot and use `parseFloat` or `parseInt`.

Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Why do you need `1.0` as compared to `1`?  They are the same value.  JavaScript has no concept of `int` or `float`, just `number`.

Comment: What is is function you wrote?  Why does it matter if its an `int` or `float`?

Comment: The function returns a random number e.g. between A and B. Depending on the initial value it can eighter bei 4,10 = > 7 (int) or 1.5, 12 => 4.25 - you get the point.

Comment: I still don't understand.  You just want the average of the numbers (wouldn't `1.5, 12` be `6.75`)?  That "example" doesn't show why it matters if it's an `int` or a `float`.

Comment: It can be any floating point number between 1.5 and 12 or whatever range you call the function with.

Comment: Oh, if the parameters are ints you want to return an int, and if they are floats, return a float.  I get it now.

Comment: The only solution you have is to pass the parameters as strings (and check if they have `.`s).  `1.0` is "converted" to `1`, and there is no way to detect that it started as `1.0`.  P.S. You can use `parseFloat` on "ints" too.

Comment: You're right, but thats not the point here. The function itself is part of something bigger and does not realy matter. Would be very handy if you had any suggestions regarding the initial problem description. But I guess there is no solution.

Comment: `1.0` is interpreted as `1` and there is no way to detect that `1.0` was entered.  So, the "solution" is to keep it as a string, and detect the `.`.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my intial post, I already did that, but hoped for some guru hint. Anyway, proof is always good.

Answer (score 4):

You've acknowledged that JavaScript only has a single `Number` type. As such, `1` is identical to `1.0`.

If you need this for display purposes, then you should use `toFixed`.

```
1..toFixed(1); // "1.0"
```

Comment: It's not for display purpose. Depending on the result of the operation the function return an float or int value using parse(Type).

Comment: @naden: You can use `parseFloat` on "ints" too.  `parseFloat('12') === 12`.

Comment: @naden: I don't understand. You've already stated that you're aware that there is no such distinction in JavaScript. If you want JavaScript to behave as though there's a distinction when there is none, then aside from using strings, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: ...JavaScript sees `1.0` and `1` as identical. JavaScript sees `"1.0"` and `"1"` as distinct. Those are your basic options.

Comment: I do, but javascript is the most surprising language I know, there is very often a hidden hack.

Comment: @naden: Yes... surprising... `;)` Sadly, aside from using strings, or some other way to manually communicate this information, there's no real solution. Passing `1.0` will always be seen as having passed `1`.

Comment: Unfortunate but all browsers behave like that, so one have to accept.

Comment: @naden: One option would be to use a custom number constructor that accepts the initial value as a string, stores that value, but gives its *toNumber* conversion for math operations. http://jsfiddle.net/rMWmr/ Not perfect, and certainly not as nice as using number literals, but maybe helpful?

Comment: Interesting idea, but way to complicated for this simple function.

Answer (score 0):

```
number%1===0
```

If that condition is `true` , it's integer, else it's float

Comment: Unfortunately for the case I pointed out you are wrong, because of the forced "cast". You may run the example code to see it prooven.

Comment: I'm not wrong it's just the way js works.
Anyway now you have to modify one out of 10 which is far better.
http://jsfiddle.net/EKmT3/5/

Comment: To be exact, you are not always wrong but regarging my case ;) It depends on the function input. See http://jsfiddle.net/7mrqM/

Comment: I don't see anything different from my post.
It's 1 of out 10 you have to deal with .0 numbers

Comment: The difference is, that the parameter is 1.0 "float" and the function alerts "int".

Comment: In C#, Java or any strong type language, maybe