# Why does javascript Number ending with a dot returns a number but when within a regex function it fails

Tags: javascript, regex

Any whole number ending in a dot returns the number in javascript console.(except decimal numbers)

like `> 1.` returns `1`. Adding `>1+1.` also works. I don't understand why

```
typeof(1) // 'number'
typeof(1.) //'number'
```

However, when I put the same number inside a function, regex test gives a wrong output.

i.e,

```
const regex = /^\d+$/ //checks if there is a number inside a string
regex.test('1') // true
regex.test(1)   //true
regex.test('1.') // false
```

The workaround I have is simply `regex.test(Number('1.'))`

Comment: `\d` is not a Number, it's a Digit and has nothing to do with js types

Comment: `Number('1.')` > `1`, that is why `^\d+$` matches it. If you want to match numbers like `10.`, `1.1` and `10`, use `/^\d+\.?\d*$/`. To match also `.0`, use `/^(?!\.$)\d*\.?\d*$/` or (to disallow empty string) `/^(?!\.?$)\d*\.?\d*$/`.

Comment: `\d` represents only a digit which not same as decimal

Comment: Try `/^(\d|.)+$/`

Comment: Since you just asked about the explanation of the behavior, it seems a dupe of [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798903/javascript-casts-floating-point-numbers-to-integers-without-cause). Closed as such.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had an answer ready to post with I suddenly couldn't. ... and as that dupe doesn't explain the _regex_ part, please open it again so I can add my answer (can't reopen single-handed...yet :)

Comment: @LGSon Do you want to explain how `/^\d+$/` works? No need to, [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) is enough. And [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EQf1RX/1) will do the rest.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to say all that + `typeof` (summerized) in a much simpler way, like this: ....... With your sample using `typeof` you ask if a value is of a certain type, and since a dot `.` is a valid part of a number, being a decimal separator, it will return `number`

_In below sample I added a few to show what happens_

---

When it comes to your _regex_, and using `\d` to test a value, you are saying, _Is this string digits_, which then will fail when it contains a dot `.`, and that is because a dot is not a digit.

Comment: I think the added dupe reasons will cover all the topics now. These misunderstandings are too basic (matching digits, dots, float/int numbers and the `Number` casting) and has been thoroughly explained. And BTW, I had plenty of the same situations when someone closed a question and I could not post my answer, it is just how SO works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Since the dupe doesn't explain anything about the _regex_ part in this question, I disagree completely with it being a dupe. ... and it has actually nothing to do with the me weren't able to post.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation @WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: @fatahn Well, it was actually me who provided the above clear explanation

Comment: @LGSon All regex explanation requests are closed as dupes of "What does this regex mean". The link is added.

Comment: oops sorry didnt see that. Thanks a lot @LGSon :)))

Comment: I think your answer is what I needed. Should I rephrase this question? @LGSon

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now it make more sense with the updated dupe links...still, a clean, easy-to-understand explanation would be of great value to be attached to this question, with which you obviously don't agree.

Comment: @fatahn No, your question works as is, it is a summarized answer that is missing, and I can't add that anymore, as it were closed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And btw, no where in those links is it explicit stated, in a simple, so beginners can easily understand it, way...which is why I am somewhat persistent in having such answer posted. Bottom line, you loose nothing, beginners get a nice, less technical answer.... and I have reopened some of my closed questions for less than that, and am not alone thinking like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean#comment73918657_22944075

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a single type for all numbers: it treats all of them as floating-point numbers. However, the dot is not displayed if there are no digits after the decimal point:

> 5.000 = 5

Also, `\d` matches a *digit*, not a number.

Comment: `it treats all of them as floating-point numbers`  Most JS Engines are a bit more clever than that.. :)

Comment: That is true but engine vs javascript developer point of view are not the same.

Comment: `\d`matches a digit, not a number - does that affect `test`? a test for digits looks for presence of a numerical value. Also `'5.' == 5` returns true. I don't understand because I expect `'5.'` to be different from `5.`

Comment: It's not the same, This is because you used lenient equality, which cast '5.' To a number , try with a strict one. `===`