# Best way to check that a variable is only an integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

What is the bet way to check that a variable is an integer?

in Python you can do:

```
 if type(x) == int
```

Is there an equally elegant equivalent in JS?

Comment: this covers it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested, but I'd suggest:

```
if (Math.round(x) == x) {
    // it's an integer
}
```

[Simplistic JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hzNrQ/).

Comment: Just a tad shorter although not exactly the same: `if (~~x == x)`

Comment: if you put `'1'` into that jsFiddle, it returns true (on Chrome). I would think this is incorrect behaviour?

Comment: @AlastairPitts: Nah, it's just coercing to a number because of `==`, use `===` if you don't want to cast string to number.

Comment: @elclanrs: Oh yeah, I keep forgetting about that from JS :/

Answer (score 0):

Use [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) (is not a number - but beware that the logic is negated) and combine with parseInt:

```
function is_int(x)
{
    return (!isNaN(x) && parseInt(x) == x)
}
```

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer), the following will also do:

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript offers typeof

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

```
   // Numbers
   typeof 37 === 'number';
   typeof 3.14 === 'number';
   typeof Math.LN2 === 'number';
   typeof Infinity === 'number';
   typeof NaN === 'number'; // Despite being "Not-A-Number"
   typeof Number(1) === 'number'; // but never use this form!
```

Comment: ... yes, but it never results in "integer" ...

Comment: I think 'number' is adequate for what I need actually.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric value of an integer's parseFloat() and parseInt() equivalents will be the same. Thus you can do like so:

```
function isInt(value){ 
    return (parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value);
}
```

Then

```
if (isInt(x)) // do work
```

Comment: You can get rid of `? true : false;` and will be shorter and should still do the same.

Comment: lol, yea, overthought, i'll fix