# How can I determine if hours and minutes were specified or not in a JavaScript Date instance?

Tags: javascript, date

How can I determine if hours and minutes were specified or not in a JavaScript Date instance?

Date object without hours:minutes:

```
var date = new Date('2013-03-15');
date.getHours();
> 1
date.getMinutes();
> 0
```

When I specify what seems to be the default hours:minutes (01:00), the return appears to be identical.

```
var date2 = new Date('2013-03-15 01:00');
date2.getHours();
> 1
date2.getMinutes();
> 0
```

Comment: You can't, only work around that by wrapping it in a custom class that can keep track of that information.

Answer (score 0):

That `+1` is because of *your local* timezone offset being applied. Oslo is Central European Time so +1 from UTC.

.`getHours()` Returns the hour (0-23) in the specified date according to local time - see [MDN Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You can use .`getUTCHours()` to return the non-localised hours instead.

Alternatively, you could us `.getTime()` which returns milliseconds and is not affected by timezone, then divide by `86400000` (milliseconds in a day) and if you get an integer then the hours, minutes, seconds were all 0.

For example:

```
d = new Date(2013, 2, 15)
if (d.getTime() / 86400000 % 1 === 0) // date is midnight
```

Note: borrowed "is integer" trick from [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer)