# How to change array push to a particular array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add only integers and ignore others in a particular array. I want to add this condition on that array's push event.

```
Array.prototype.push = function(){   

if(condition){

   //execute push if true

  }

  else
  {

    //return false

  }

}
```

Help me how to code this?  This affects all the array in my code. I want to check this condition on push only for a particular array. what are the ways to achieve it?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't add it to the prototype. Rather, just create some special container class for this array that does the check for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QhJzE/4

Add the method directly to the array:

```
var nums = [];

nums.push = function(n) {
    if (isInt(n))
        Array.prototype.push.call(this, n);
}

nums.push(2);
nums.push(3.14);
nums.push('dawg');

console.log(nums);
```

(See [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer) for `isInt` function.)

Here's some great information: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/. What I've shown here is called "direct extension" in that article.