# JavaScript check if the value is number, but allow no leading zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

I am currently working on a project where I need to check if the user input a number value. The problem comes when he input a number starting with a decimal point (`.20`). I've been looking for a solution, but now I just give up. Neither isNaN or isNumeric works. Also tried to check like: `if(value > 0)`, but this only works when the user input a leading zero.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**SOLVED:** isNaN doesn't work for me because I use parseInt() instead of parseFloat(). Now everything works just fine. I want the administrators to excuse me for the dumb question I asked! This thread could now be deleted.

Comment: Try `if (+value > 0)`.

Comment: Or `parseFloat(value) > 0`

Comment: I don't get it, why wouldn't isNaN work -> http://jsfiddle.net/6NrZA/1/

Comment: check my answer i posted this 26 min ago pls make it answer

Comment: *"isNaN doesn't work for me because I use parseInt() instead of parseFloat()"*: Uh? You don't have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` at all, just pass the value to `isNaN`. It will be converted to a number, just like if you used the unary plus operator. *"This thread could now be deleted."* That's not how it works. You mark the answer the solved the problem as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Working Demohttp://jsfiddle.net/sPt7q/1

use

```
if(parseFloat(n) > 0){}
```

**js in fiddle**

```
var n = '.2';
if (n > 0) {
    alert(n);
}
if(parseFloat(n) > 0){
    alert(parseFloat(n));
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `parseFloat` if `n` *is* already a number?

Comment: oh you are correct i updated the code pls check now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function isInt(n) {
   return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}
```

from: [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

this does fail on 0.0 though.

Answer (score 0):

A better and fool-proof way is to use regular expression:

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$');
```

or

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$');
```

The user input will be a string (from a form field). Check that string against this regex and that should work.

example:

```
 if(reg.test(userInput)) {
  //returns true
} else {
  //returns false
}
```

Comment: *Why* is it better than using `isNaN`? Do you have any facts to support your claim? Btw, your expression would not handle `'.2'` correctly.

Comment: updated my regex. This will handle cases like 2, 0.2, .2 (without leadng zero), 2.222 etc. This regex checks for a number which can be a decimal also.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why it is "better".

Comment: I would say better because it checks the exact pattern while eliminating use of parseInt(), isNaN and other number-manipulating functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var val = .21;
if (!isNaN(val) && val.toString().indexOf('.') == -1) {
    console.log('valid number:' + val);
} else {
    console.log('invalid number: ' + val);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/fmcqT/1/)**