# Detect if number is INT or FLOAT in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently taking input in a text-box and on-submit, I am validating the input, the input needs to be a number greater than 0, it should be integer and not contain decimal point. The problem is I am not able to find any method by which we can detect it is integer or contains decimal point. Here is the code I am using.

```
    txt[5] = $(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val();
    if (txt[5] == "" || isNaN(txt[5]) || txt[5] <= 0) 
    {
        alert("Incorrect Quantity");
        return false;
    }
```

Basically as you see I am validating the input given by user, I want to show them a message if the input is wrong, so I am currently using **txt[5]%1!=0** to make sure only INT is allowed, but I am open to new answers.

Comment: Why not simply use `parseInt()`? It truncates floats and 'unparseable' input will return `NaN`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a number is float or integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Comment: @FelixKling: Bear in mind that the answer to that dupe will not work if the supplied argument is a string, because `typeof "5"` is `string`.

Comment: @MattEllen: I don't think it's very difficult to adjust the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt[5] = parseInt($(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val(), 10);
```

This won't validate the number (see [Nirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481788/825789) for that), but if it's not an int, it will be converted to one.

Comment: unless it's not a number

Comment: Yes, that will be trapped by the checks the OP already has in place.

Comment: What is the "10" at the last?

Comment: It forces the number to be parsed ad a base-10 int. Older browsers interpret numbers starting with zero as octals. @Ankur

Comment: @MattEllen Comma, fixed

Comment: Looking at the ', I got confused, just hold on I am just testing it.

Comment: Sorry @Ankur, I'm on my ipad, touch keyboard + autocorrect causes some mistakes...

Comment: Basically as you see I am validating the input given by user, I want to show them a message if the input is wrong, so I am currently using "txt[5]%1!=0" to make sure only INT is allowed, but I am open to new answers.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave this answer as it is, since there are other answers addressing that.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to parse the text as a Number, coerce to integer, and see if they are equal:

```
var numbertxt5 = Number(txt[5]);
if(numbertxt5 | 0 == numbertxt5) { /* int */
} else if (!isNaN(numbertxt5)) { /* float */
} else { /* not a number */
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because JavaScript has only one numerical type called `number`. It is neither `int` nor `float`, but it behaves like both at a time. However, you do have two methods that you can use for this `parseInt` and `parseFloat`.

```
var result = parseInt($(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val());
txt[5] = result;
```

Using `parseFloat` is similar. Eg.

```
var result = parseFloat($(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val());
txt[5] = result;
```

The second example is not what you want but it is here just for your reference.

UPDATE: @bfavaretto made a good point with using *radix* which I omitted in `parseInt`. Have a look at this page for reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp