# Test if string is Integer with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, testing, text, input

what is the function which test if a string is an Integer or not like the method :

```
jQuery.isNumeric()
```

i want to test an input html element :

```
<input id='distance' type='text' />
```

thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check a value is float or int in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311572/check-a-value-is-float-or-int-in-jquery) And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Comment: That's the function. What else do you need to know?

Comment: @Dan It's not a duplicate of that. That question is about deciding which it is, int or float. This question just wants to know if it's any kind ofnumber.

Comment: Ok well there seem to be plenty of questions on this already - here's another similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600763/check-if-a-variable-contains-a-numerical-value-in-javascript and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272696/checking-if-number-entered-is-a-digit-in-jquery

Comment: the case for the function isNumeric() are :     http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/        but i am asking how can i test if it is integer or not

Comment: @Dan Easier to just ask than to try searching for a question you may not know how to phrase!

Comment: Using isNAN? isNaN("Hello") => true

Comment: @Mardoxx yeah but he does know how to phrase it - Can just google "Test if string is Integer with Jquery".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thank you for your contributions i found the answer :

```
if(Math.floor($('#distance').val()) == $('#distance').val() && $.isNumeric($('#distance').val()))
 { 
 alert('yes its an int!');
 }
```

Comment: how it could be possible if it returns the alert for the input 876ffff654??  This is not true.

Comment: @LeaveCover give us the test link please

Answer (score -1):

I use this

```
function IsInteger(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: OK
Number(n) returns NaN, so if 'not a number'  it won't equal n.
The  n % 1 will return 0 if an integer. 
Something else mean you have a float

Comment: IsInteger("555445")===> result  =false

Comment: If function is updated to the following, it would work for passing in string input.
function IsInteger(n){
    return Number(n) == n && n % 1 === 0;
}

Using "==" instead of "===" so "555445" == 5554455 will result in true.

Answer (score -4):

sorry I didn't notice integer when I answered, here is another type check:

```
if($.type($(#distance).val())==="number")
```

please see:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/

Comment: it returns "string" and not "number" because the input element has the attribute : type=text