# jQuery : How to find a number is float or integer?

Tags: jquery

How to find that a number is `float` or `integer`?

```
1.25 --> float  
1.00 --> float
1 --> integer  
0.25 --> float
```

Comment: @Arian In my question for value of `1.00` it should be return float. In provide your link it will return `integer`.

Comment: `1.00` is an integer as the decimal values are extraneous. If the issue is that you need to detect that the value **may** be a float at some point in the future based on its current value, then you cannot reliably do that in JS due to it's data typing model.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311572/check-a-value-is-float-or-int-in-jquery#answer-20311638) , you may try it like this.

```js
var value = 1;
if(typeof value === 'number'){
   if(value % 1 === 0){
      // int
      console.log('integer');
   } else{
      // float
      console.log('float');
   }
} else{
   // not a number
   console.log('not a number');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks but i need that it should be consider `1.00` as a float.