# Difference between both variable declaration

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a simple code to check if session variable is not set then page redirect to another page usign javascript. My code is:

```
var userLogin = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id']; ?>";
if (typeof userLogin == "undefined")
{
    $(location).attr('href', 'http://www.example.com/');
}
```

But it's not working because if session is not set then it assign:

```
var userLogin = "";
```

My question is:
What is difference between both variable declaration:

```
var userLogin = "";
```

and

```
var userLogin;
```

Comment: the first is assigning an empty string to userLogin. The 2nd one leaves it undefined.

Comment: ......why don't you just redirect with PHP?

Comment: This is in addition to @MartyWallace. Why not use [gettype()](http://at2.php.net/gettype) in php and then redirect in php also?

Comment: I would assume it's because headers have already been sent at this point, but that's definitely the way to go if it can be done earlier in this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `var userLogin` assigns a value of `undefined` to `userLogin`, while `var userLogin = ""` assigns an empty string as its value.

Use `if (!userLogin)` instead of `if (typeof userLogin == "undefined")`.

---

When writing an expression

```
if (x) { ... }
```

JavaScript considers the following `x` values to be `false`

`undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `""` (empty string), and `false`

**All other values for `x` are considered `true`**

Comment: perfect short answer +1

Comment: +1 nice work. You might want to mention which values JavaScript considers `false`

Comment: @maček I thought about it, but decided I don't even want to open that can of worms. For example is `"00.00"` worth mentioning? What about `[0]`?

Comment: @DaggNabbit, it's actually pretty straightforward. I made an edit for you :)

Comment: @maček I don't think it's that straightforward... the empty array, an array containing a single falsey element, strings like `"0"`, etc. are all falsey. Even their boxed versions, like `new String()`, are falsey. Also, `NaN` is neither truthy nor falsey. It's fair to say that all the values you listed (except NaN) are falsey, but saying that all other values are truthy isn't quite accurate.

Comment: @maček in fact it's even more complicated than that... I'm considering "falsey" to mean "*x* is falsey if `x == false` evaluates to `true`", but you could also define falsey as "*x* is falsey if `!!x` evaluates to `false`," which would change things for boxed values, arrays, strings representing 0, and NaN (so I guess the definition you are using is more like this).

Comment: I guess the definition you're using is appropriate when considering `if` statements, but in other contexts it's important to be aware of all the type conversion that goes on under the hood. I've seen people [make this kind of mistake before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3886106/886931).

Comment: @DaggNabbit, Right, `!!"0" // true`, `!![0] // true`, and `!!(new String) // true`. As soon as you use `==`, that's where you introduce problems. I don't think I've ever wrote `if (x == false)`, probably because of all the gotchas you're listing. I always use `===` when testing equality, and I always use `!!x` to "cast" as a boolean.

Comment: Either way, I added a little disclaimer around the edit I made :)

Comment: @maček I looked around a bit and your definition of falsey (even though you didn't actually say the word "falsey" I guess that's what we're talking about) seems to be the generally accepted definition... which leaves me wondering what to call things that, when compared to `false` with the abstract equality operator, evaluate to `true`. Maybe there isn't a name for them. The thing is, you can't avoid all the automatic typecasting weirdness just by avoiding `==`. Consider an expression like `"5" % (true + true + true)`. Anyway, sorry for wall-o-comments... I might ask a new question about this.