# Check if number is an integer in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some JS:

```
var updateAmount = function (amount, rate) {
    if (rate > 0 && amount.length > 0 && !isNaN(amount) && amount > 0) {
        amount = Math.round(rate * amount * 100) / 100; // multiply rate with amount and then round to 2 decimals
        $('.you-get').show();
        $('#you-get').text(amount + ' ' + $currencyTo.find(':selected').text());
    } else {
        $('.you-get').hide();
    }
};
```

What I need is a clause that checks if the value generated from `amount + $currencyTo.find` is a whole number, if it is **then add `.00`** to the end of it.

Comment: amount = Number(amount); rate = Number(rate); will this help ?

Comment: Maybe amount.toFixed(2); I'm not sure what you mean by amount + $currencyTo.find as that seams to be a string and not a number since you are appending empty space between + ' ' +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var updateAmount = function (amount, rate) {
  if (rate > 0 && amount.length > 0 && !isNaN(amount) && amount > 0) {
    amount = Math.round(rate * amount * 100) / 100; // multiply rate with amount and then round to 2 decimals
    $('.you-get').show();
    var val = amount + '' + $currencyTo.find(':selected').text();
    if (val === parseInt(val)){// check if val is an Int
      $('#you-get').text(val.toFixed(2));//add .00 if amount + $currencyTo.find is an Int
    }else{  
      $('#you-get').text(val);
    }
  }else{
    $('.you-get').hide();
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it doesn't seem to add .00 if  there's no decimal place in the variable val?

Comment: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6rF6/2/) : in this example, `toFixed` adds .00 on an integer.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(amount === parseInt(amount)) //returns `true` if it's a integer


var updateAmount = function (amount, rate) {
    if (rate > 0 && amount.length > 0 && !isNaN(amount) && amount > 0 && amount === parseInt(amount)) { //Edited this line
        if(amount === parseInt(amount)) amount += '.00'; //Added this line
        amount = Math.round(rate * amount * 100) / 100; // multiply rate with amount and then round to 2 decimals
        $('.you-get').show();
        $('#you-get').text(amount + ' ' + $currencyTo.find(':selected').text());
    } else {
        $('.you-get').hide();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **[.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** method.

```
amount = Math.round(rate * amount * 100) / 100;
amount = amount.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the remainder to check if the number is a whole number? E.g.

```
var val = parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat($currencyTo.find(':selected').text());
if ( val % 1 == 0 ) { /* whole number */ } else {/* not whole number */ }
```

You could also check that `!isNaN(val)`

This is essentially the answer suggested from a similar question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer)