# Array.every returns false instead of type error

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

In practising various JavaScript code katas, I came across this problem:

**Write a function isIntArray with the below signature**

```
function isIntArray(arr) {
    return true;
}
```

- returns true if every element in an array is an integer
- returns true if array is empty.
- returns false for every other input.

I had made my own solution to this, but one of the accepted solutions was the following:

```
function isIntArray(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(function (x) { return Math.floor(x)=== x });
}
```

Now i understand how the Math.floor section works when determining if x is a decimal, but what i don't understand is how it doesn't fall over when it encounters something like:

```
var arr = [1,2,"asd",NaN,5];
```

I Tried reading through some guides on Math.floor and Array.prototype.every and i can't find anything that explains this. Surely if x was a string then Math.floor(x) === x should return a TypeError?

Comment: Did you just try `Math.floor("asd")` and see that you get `NaN` as the returned value, and `NaN === "asd"` is still false.

Comment: The JavaScript `===` operator won't ever give you any sort of "type error".

Comment: I tried Math.floor("asd") and got undefined is not a function in the console

Comment: OK, great, but that's not an example of the `===` operator throwing an error. (Also, `Math.floor("asd")` works just fine in my browser.)

Comment: Various options for that inline function given to `every` (to check if the item is a number) is in  fact [discussed at length in another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3885817/419956). [One answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20779354/419956) discusses [the MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Polyfill) that uses `Math.floor` with some added edge-case checks too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jbailie1992/gL2kc1e6/, open console(i did this in Chrome) and Run. Im getting a type error

Comment: That error is a result of your spelling "floor" as "Floor".

Comment: Yup `Math.floor` works just fine in the console. Personally I would probably have just written it `return arr.length ? arr.filter(Number).length === arr.length : false;` and dropped the `every` ?

Comment: @Pointy Ha that it is, good spot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Surely if `x` was a string then `Math.floor(x) === x` should return a `TypeError`?

Nope. Most mathematical functions and operations return `NaN` if one of the operand cannot be converted into number and then operated upon.

So, it becomes    `Math.floor("asd") === "asd"` is essentially

```
NaN === "asd" // which is obviously false
```

Comment: Ah ok I see now, would this be one of those quirks I hear people often talk about when discussing JavaScript?

Comment: @jbailie1991 it definitely isn't. `NaN`  is acronym for "Not A Number", so it makes sense. There are a lot of other quirks in javascript, but actually it's just how it's designed.

Comment: Right, I understand the process now. Also clears up how it can evaluate NaN in the array as well, Thanks

Comment: @jbailie1991 great going! Also glad to have helped you :)