# How to check if value is number

Tags: angularjs

I have this function :

```
 $scope.SearchTicketEvent = function (ticketPinOrEvent)
            {
                if (ticketPinOrEvent != undefined)
                {

                 if (ticketPinOrEvent.length == 10)
                    {

                     $scope.PinTicketSearch(ticketPinOrEvent);

                    }
                }


            }
```

How can i check if ticketPinOrEvent is number ? I tried with `angular.isNumber(ticketPinOrEvent)` but i dont get anything?

Comment: what are you getting when you call angular.isNumber ?

Comment: Did you mean type `int` or `float`?

Comment: @dhavalcengg when i try with console log if i enter 1234567890 i get false

Comment: `angular.isNumber(1234567890)` => `true`. Check the value of your argument `ticketPinOrEvent`, which maybe `undefined`.

Comment: @ShaojiangCai its not undefined...it i enter like u hardcoding number i get true but when i pass like parameters i get false

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check that a number is float or integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to use angular.isNumber

```
    if ( !isNaN(ticketPinOrEvent) && angular.isNumber(+ticketPinOrEvent)) {
    }
```

Comment: why i need to use + ??

Comment: You must be taking this value from view using some text box or something else... for text box this is always a string.. you need to convert string to number before passing it to angular.isNumber method. + is overloaded operator to convert any value to number.

Comment: but what ever i enter then i get true...i enter ffffffffff it returns me true

Comment: same as before...i get true if i enter leters and numbers

Comment: `typeof NaN` will return a number in your case. NaN compares unequal `(via ==, !=, ===, and !==)` to any other value -- including to another `NaN` value.

Comment: sorry.. i forget that.. I should use isNaN method of javascript updated my answer..

Comment: @dhavalcengg again i get true both times(letters and numbers)

Comment: Perfect answer, Thank you @dhavalcengg

Comment: what is this `angular` is it class  ?

Answer (score 8):

In Angular 6 this works without using any prefix.

Example:

```
if(isNumber(this.YourVariable)){
    // your Code if number
}
else {
    // Your code if not number
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You might use the `typeof` to test if a variable is number.

```
if (typeof ticketPinOrEvent === 'number') {
    $scope.PinTicketSearch(ticketPinOrEvent);
}
```

Or might try this:

```
if (!isNaN(ticketPinOrEvent) && angular.isNumber(ticketPinOrEvent)) {
    $scope.PinTicketSearch(ticketPinOrEvent);
}
```

[Testing against NaN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

> NaN compares unequal `(via ==, !=, ===, and !==)` to any other value --
>   including to another NaN value.  Use `Number.isNaN()` or `isNaN()` to most
>   clearly determine whether a value is NaN.  Or perform a
>   self-comparison: NaN, and only NaN, will compare unequal to itself.

Comment: Angular 1.4.1 source code Line 628: `function isNumber(value) {return typeof value === 'number';}`