# Check if data from ng-model is a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Typically data from ng-model biding from input is stored as a string. How can I check if user typed a number or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if value is number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558283/how-to-check-if-value-is-number)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the angular [IsNumber](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber) feature,

```
 if (angular.isNumber(modelvar) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add validation on the `input` to prevent anything but numbers,
[Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox)

Or better, use a **validation engine** to check inputs and show warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

`<input type="number">`

To ensure that in the HTML it's a number, and to check in angular;

```
if(typeof(VARIABLE) != "number"){
    console.log("error, variable is not a number");
    return;
}
```

Hope it helps!