# Is there a typeguard syntax for restricting a class property to integer?

Tags: typescript, integer, biginteger

I have an application which uses a lot of currency values, and several classes which reflect 'money' properties.

I plan on storing everything as integers and only converting to a decimal representation in views.

Is some property declaration guard syntax I can use to to ensure at compile time, that an error will be flagged by an attempt to assign a regular number which can't be certain isn't an integer to one of these fields?

For example:

```
 class Account {
     name: string
     private balance : integer = 0;
     maxWithdrawal: integer = 0;
     maxOverdraft : integer = 0;
     ...

     deposit(amount : number) {
         this.balance += deposit;   // flags some kind of "deposit may not be an integer" error.
     }

 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if value is number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558283/how-to-check-if-value-is-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInt` currently is the only Integer type (apart from fixed sets like `1|2|3`). What TS maintainers [say](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/195#issuecomment-395828330):

> BigInt seems like a "close enough" fit for these use cases and doesn't require us inventing new expression-level syntax.

Here are two possible solutions:

1.) [`BigInt`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#bigint)

```
class AccountBigInt {
  private balance: bigint = 4n;

  deposit(deposit: bigint) {
    this.balance += deposit;  
  }
}

const a = new AccountBigInt()
a.deposit(3n)
// a.deposit(3.3n) // error
// a.deposit(3.3)  // error
```

---

2.) [Branded](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) `Integer` type

```
type Integer = number & { __brand__: "__integer__" } // branded primitive type

// use this as the only way / factory method to create an Integer type
const int = (val: number): Integer => {
  if (Number.isInteger(val)) return val as unknown as Integer
  throw Error("val is not an integer.")
}

const i1 = int(3)
const i2 = int(3.3) // throws at run-time
const sum = int(3) + int(4) // works, Integer is a subtype of number

class AccountBranded {
  private balance: Integer = int(4);

  deposit(deposit: Integer) {
    // wrap with int(), because this.balance + deposit returns number
    // you also could create an add function for Integer
    this.balance = int(this.balance + deposit)
  }
}

const a2 = new AccountBranded()
a2.deposit(int(3)) // works
a2.deposit(3) // error, number not assignable to Integer (OK)
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99&ssl=42&ssc=15&pln=42&pc=68#code/PTAEEEBsBcFMCcB2BDaBLAbrAXKARmgOZqLQCwAULAB4AOA9vNKAN6gC%20llAxpMgM78I3bvQCupAEJEAkqVaVQoWvEypY%20ZH0Tcc%20IiWYBeUABZEAbi4UlAE1gN%20aaAAp7j57gLFSASgU2SqDQABZo-AB0eFrIOhoA1Cbu9E7QFkqKHJScFDz0iPzMyKAmiLAA7sKiEtDShHKuvpTIEcmpLgDMiE0UIKAtbc6dEV3%20fQjwjJR9Aw4pQx0j-qDj8JPw1tNgUHBIqJh6ePCx9rbBAJ60sPzW0JcaDbCECCWgiGIAtngvAGSsoAB9AFHE5A3AAIiBhieCCB4KyuQoogKzEMrxcGC0uHeXwQvlwj2e8BKAD4Ako0AAzUAuAByn2%208Ai4UJCAxWl8-ngsGgYiQoExkH6QgkAGtEPRyohhaBWRtAqFJpUAKJrRgucGC0DhN70IrS6FEiLgno5PIo7UARlehk6PWRhW1ACYbaRhh0xmBFZKhKhQPAJABadAfWDmx38T6u1we0DxbVu0ye0DlRii-gAGllpBhxJ1xUjeDuV1A9GpOMZ1l4AiE4BE4ikx0Qp3JylUmLgmm0ugJOaJ0ZcSasiLsc3ag2gvbgRP8LEySj65WOtBTzhCCcaWdC4SiMTicdAE-9PL5BTeDIQ8%20CYUi0W7GhMtu3t73ugPE56ShyZqR%20UdyBdUoKiqBtaibU4XB6ADWjHIZbQ9ZNU3gdNmidGCPBjZZVnWLMKxeCUikEIgUDwSANGgehs2nF4XAAeQAaV8IA)

---

#### Update: On `BigInt` support

Currently, `BigInt` [isn't adopted widely](https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint) (2020-01-10). As far as I know, there is no "real" polyfill library out there - it would have to change the core JS logic for operators like `+`, `-` and others. That would be a fairly sophisticated approach!

A [well-known](https://v8.dev/features/bigint#polyfilling-transpiling) approach is to use [JSBI](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi) library (see also [here](https://javascript.info/bigint#polyfills)). Once `BigInt` support is better, you can transpile back to native `BigInt` without rewriting your code using a [babel plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/babel-plugin-transform-jsbi-to-bigint).

Comment: Perfect.   Thanks

Comment: I'm a little concerned that I will have to target ESNext to in order to use BigInt.  I gather there is a thing called "polyfils" to make my app run in say safari, which I gather doesnt' support BigInt yet.  Do I need to do something special to make sure this works?

Comment: Oof.  Looks tedious to have to change my code from let x = 2n; to  x = JSBI.BigInt(2).  Will I have problems ESNext if I am using these classes inside of an Angular application though?   the comment in the answer below suggests that somehow if you are using Node.js the issue might disappear.

Comment: yeah, that is the trade-off until it is supported more widely (at least you don't need re-writes later on). You can go with the branded solution (2nd alternative), if you want to have max. compatibility and ease of use.

Comment: why should you get problems with jsbi and esnext? concerning node: it supports BigInt with 10.4, as far as I know. And you can upgrade server-side (node) far easier than all client browsers.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no built-in type that restricts values to be integers in TypeScript.
As such, there is no way to catch such errors at compile time.

If you want, you can check for integers at run time.
You could make your own "boxed" integer, and use `Number.isInteger()` to ensure the boxed value is an integer. For example:

```js
class BoxedInteger {
  public readonly value: number;

  public constructor(value: number) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(value)) {
      throw new Error(`Number is not an integer: ${value}`);
    }
    this.value = value;
  }
}

const a = new BoxedInteger(5).value; // ok, a = 5
const b = new BoxedInteger(5.5).value; // error!
```

[*] Note:
keep in mind the limitations of `Number.isInteger()`
For example: `Number.isInteger(5.0000000000000001); // true`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Comment: This appears to be wrong.  BigInt is a type that is restricted to integers

Comment: True, the `bigint` type will give you compile time errors. However, at the time of writing, browser support is not great for big integers. If you're running on Node or have the luxury of telling your users to use specific browsers, then go for it. https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint