# Why does javascript accept a decimal as an integer

Tags: javascript, html, input, integer

I have this html:

```
<input type='number' id='length' step='0.1' min='0'; max='5'>Length
```

and this Javascript

```
num=document.getElementById('length').value;
if(num==1 || 2 || 3 || 4|| 5){
num='0'+num;
}
```

My problem is this: while I only want the code inside the brackets to execute if the number from the input is an integer, it also activates if it detects 0.8 or some other decimal. Any Idea why? How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: There are no integers in javascript, only `number`s. Also, when evaluating numbers, all values except 0 equals `true` so `|| 2` equals `true`

Comment: Your `if` logic is broken.

Comment: Unless you only want those specific ints, use something like this, rather than a long `if`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Comment: `min='0';` →`min='0'`

Comment: `num==1 || 2 || 3 || 4|| 5` actually means `(num==1) || (2) || (3) || (4) || (5)`, so your code will always evaluated to true

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yeah. Thanks. Just a bit rusty. First time using Js in a while. I was so used to JQuery, and then here I am working on a project where the circumstances don't permit me to use it. Got a bit spoiled with Jquery

Comment: The `if` statement has nothing to do with jQuery. It's basic JavaScript.

Comment: @Vohuman I know.  I was just saying that I haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure `num` is a whole number, without having to define all possibilities, use:

```
if (num % 1 == 0)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I made a stupid error. Bit rusty at JS. I will accept in morning, can't now cause time limit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
if (num == 1 || num == 2 || num == 3 || num == 4 || num == 5)
```

*WRONG* - otherwise it will compare 2 with 2 and says it's true for the 4 last 'if' parameters.

*CORRECTO* - any number in JS is considered as true.

Comment: "compare 2 with 2 "? Any number which is not 0 is considered a truthy value in JavaScript. (I haven't *voted)

Comment: Yeah what @Vohuman said is what's actually happening. No I did the voting. The explanation of why the code isn't working is spreading misinformation.

Comment: this is the correct way to compare, but it doesn't solve the OP's problem, as this only checks for 5 integers but there are much, much more other integers

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc it does solve it because I only needed to check for a few. In case you didn't notice, the input form had a maximum value of five, so I only needed to check for integers 1-5.give him his vote back.

Answer (score 2):

**Why:**

```
num==1 || 2 || 3 || 4|| 5
```

equals to:

```
(num==1) || 2 || 3 || 4|| 5
```

so if `num` is `"1"` (always a string type), the expression returns `true`, otherwise `2` (also a **truthy** value), eventually your `if` statement always succeeds.

**How to fix:**

```
// implicitly converts the string type into number type before comparison
// returns true if it is an integer-like string
num == Math.floor(num)
```

So you could do it like this:

```
if (num == Math.floor(num) && num > 0 && num < 6) {
    // an integer-like string that meets the requirement [1, 5]
}
```

But remember, the `num` is still **`string`** type now. If you want a `number`, do:

```
num = +num
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the "If" loop:

```
if (num == 1 || num == 2 || num == 3 || num == 4 || num == 5)
```