# How to tell if "123@231.23" is not a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

`parseInt("123@231.23")` returns 123, which is a number.

There are tons of functions out there to detect if something is a number or not already, but they all **depend on parseInt**.

What is another generic way of detecting that this is not an integer without using regex?

Comment: What is wrong with using `parseInt`? The functions I've seen which use it to determine if something is a number would say that your input is not one.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Comment: What about some nice docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Comment: @NabilKadimi - not supported in Internet Exploder

Comment: parseInt("123@231.23") returns 123 ...

Comment: @JaromandaX Prototypes !

Comment: @NabilKadimi - I bow to your superior intellect, well played sir

Comment: Number.isInteger("123") returns false

Comment: @JaromandaX Bow to your creator

Comment: I know that..... but I also  want to detect that "123" IS a number

Comment: @JaromandaX Polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Polyfill

Comment: I got that when you said Prototypes!

Comment: So what's wrong with a regex? E.g. the "stricter parse function" example on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: **Your accepted answer is wrong**, check in the comments to read why!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isNaN("123@231.23"))
{
 alert("IsNaN - not a number");
}
else
{
 alert ("it is a number");
}
```

I'm assuming that OP need to distinguish if input is a number or not. If input is float or integer looks irrelevant to his problem. 
Maybe, I'm wrong...

EDIT:
Alright, to keep everyone happy, integer in javasript is pretty big. 
How big integer is in javascript check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin).

Asking if something is integer is asking is it a whole number between 9007199254740992 and -9007199254740992. Wholeness of the number you may check using modulus `%`

```js
$("#cmd").click(function (e) { ChectIfInteger( $("#txt").val() ) });

function ChectIfInteger(myval){

  if (isNaN(myval)){ 
    alert("not integer (not number)")   
  }
  else{
  
    //it is a number but it is integer?
    if( myval % 1 == 0 ){
    
      if (myval <= 9007199254740992 && myval >= -9007199254740992)
        {
          alert("it is integer in javascript");
        }
      else{
          alert ("not integer");
      }
    }
    else{
      alert("nope, not integer");
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" id="cmd" value="test input">
```

Comment: `isNaN("123")` returns false

Comment: Because `isNan` returns true if the arg is *not* a number. 123 is a number so it returns false.

Comment: @NeoWang "**is** **N**ot **A** **N**umber" so false means it is a number in this case...

Comment: `isNaN(" "): false`

`isNaN(false): false`

`isNaN(true): false`

Comment: Well `isNaN` is not really safe unless you know what you're testing. In this case it's fine, but it's not really what `isNaN` means.

Comment: The question is asking about integers, `isNaN()` doesn't really do that. And it's best to avoid the global `isNaN()` due to the confusing special cases.

Comment: *This anser is wrong*, this just check numbers, not integer numbers, for example `isNaN(123231.23)` will produce `true` cause it is a number, but should produce `false ` since it is not an integer number!!!!

Comment: I'm assuming that OP need to distinguish is input a number or not. 
Is input float or integer looks irrelevant to his question.
Maybe, I'm wrong...

Comment: @dllhell: `isNaN()` doesn't work that way: it checks if a value is `NaN` and also does some auto-coercion for its input. But this does _not_ mean that if `isNaN(x) == false` then `x` must be a number!

Comment: @dllhell maybe you should re-read the title of the question :)

Comment: Please provide better solution

Comment: *You* should provide a better solution, not us. 
You should remove your answer, or at least edit it with solutions provided by other answer...

Comment: My solution is adequate for OP's problem and it's acceptance is a proof. Otherwise, OP should unaccept this answer and accept other one.

Comment: The question was: What is another generic way of detecting that this **is not an integer**? Your solution provide a valid answer for `123@231.23`, that's why the OP accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert back to String and compare:

```
String(parseInt("123"))=="123" // true
String(parseInt("123.sdfs"))=="123.sdfs" //false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check *"for valid integer"* you must combine `isNaN` with something else like this:

```
function isValidInteger(numberToTest) {
  return !(isNaN(numberToTest) || String(parseInt(numberToTest)) !== numberToTest.toString());    
}
```

This will evaluate like:

```
console.log(isValidInteger('123@231.23')); // false
console.log(isValidInteger('123231.23')); // false
console.log(isValidInteger('12323')); // true
console.log(isValidInteger(1e-1)); // false
console.log(isValidInteger('1e-1')); // false
```

And this work even with numbers.
[Here is PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xv05TYFU8Jywtylo9KUv?p=preview) to test.

Comment: `isValidInteger("1e-1")` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to test for integers:

```
function isInt(str) {
    if (typeof str !== 'number' && typeof str !== 'string') {
        return false;
    }

    return str % 1 === 0;
}
```

Just note that strings / numbers like "123.0" evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another one that doesn't rely on string stuff:

```
function looksLikeInteger(n) {
  return +n == n && +n === ~~n;
}
```

Probably should be called "looksLikeJavaScriptInteger" because it only works for 32-bit integers. It coerces to numeric with unary `+` and then checks for equality (so ugly strings and objects are tossed out there) and then checks to make sure that the numeric value doesn't change when coerced to an integer.