# Text input always parsed as string by jQuery - how to retrieve val as int or float?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-input

I am doing some calculations based on values from two text inputs. Values could be floats or ints. The calculations are triggered on the `keyup` event.

So at the moment I have to evaluate the val to determine if it is a float or int and then use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` as appropriate.

This seems a bit hacky or overkill. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/2hw0tnhb/

HTML:

```
<label id="x-label" for="x">Float</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="x" id="x" value="29.7" class="axis"/>

<br/>
<br/>

<label id="y-label" for="y">Int</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="y" id="y" value="21" class="axis"/>
```

JS:

```
var $x = $('#x');
var $y = $('#y');
var $axis = $('.axis');
var x_label = $('#x-label');
var y_label = $('#y-label');

$axis.keyup(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var axis = 'x';

    if($this.attr('id') === 'y') axis = 'y';

    //check if int or float:
    if(parseFloat(val) > Math.floor(parseFloat(val))){
        //it is a float - use parseFloat()   
        if( axis === 'x' ){
           x_label.text('Float'); 
        }else{
           y_label.text('Float'); 
        }        
    }
    else{
        //it is an int - use parseInt()
        if( axis === 'x' ){
           x_label.text('Int'); 
        }else{
           y_label.text('Int'); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a leading `+` and the result will be numeric, int or float:

```
var val = +$this.val(); //or +this.value
```

And you can use `type="number"` to keep entries into `.axis` numeric:

```
<input type="number" name="x" id="x" value="29.7" class="axis"/>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var $x = $('#x');
    var $y = $('#y');
    var $axis = $('.axis');
    var x_label = $('#x-label');
    var y_label = $('#y-label');

    $axis.keyup(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var val = +$this.val();
        var axis = this.name;
        
        console.log( val );
        console.log( val + 3.5 );
        console.log( val + 4 );
    })
    .trigger('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="x-label" for="x">Float</label>
<br/>
<input type="number" name="x" id="x" value="29.7" class="axis"/>

<br/>
<br/>

<label id="y-label" for="y">Int</label>
<br/>
<input type="number" name="y" id="y" value="21" class="axis"/>
```

> **Unary plus (+)**
>   The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but **attempts to converts it into a
>   number**, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can
>   convert non-numbers, **unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of
>   converting something into a number, because it does not perform any
>   other operations on the number**. It can convert string representations
>   of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false,
>   and null. Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed)
>   formats are supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for
>   hex). If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to **NaN**.

Ref: [**Arithmetic Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: That's really cool - I've never seen `+` placed before something like this. How does this work exactly? I know about `type="number"` but I think browser support is a bit patchy.

Comment: I'm upvoting this but what I've always preferred about parseInt and/or parseFloat is that they more clearly express the intent

Comment: splendid solution worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems hacky, yes, however this is one of those unfortunate side-effects of JavaScript's type system. Checking that a number is an integer can be done by [looking for a remainder when dividing by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer):

```
function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

You could also refactor your code a little to make it feel less bloated:

```
$axis.keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var axis = $this.attr('id');
    var val = $this.val();
    var isInt = isInt(val);
    var text = (isInt) ? 'Int' : 'Float';

    var labelMap = {
        x: x_label,
        y: y_label
    };

    labelMap[axis].text(text);
});
```