# Regex for pattern integer,integer or float

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate entry in textbox using regex.
The pattern should be

```
integer, integer or float
```

so valid entries can be

```
1234, 1234
123, 123.45
```

and invalid entries will be

```
abd, 123
123, abc
abc, abc
```

so far I have tried

```
var entry = "123,123.4" 
var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]+,(?:[\d+(\.\d+]+,?){0,1}$");
res = patt.test(entry);
```

but it returns false, though it should return true

Comment: The first one intenger (every) and the second one Integer of Float?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fP8qY5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace you regExp by this one:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]+,[0-9]+.?[0-9]*");
```

I think this is what you want.

To accept space after comma:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]+, [0-9]+.?[0-9]*");
```

For case of 1a it's needed to ad $ in the end

Comment: You should escape your dot

Comment: What are you trying to do with the '?+' at the end? Did you mean to put a '*'?

Comment: This works, only can you update it to even accept space please. So if its 123, 123.4 (with a space) it should also pass. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need it to accept spaces you should probably add a couple of \s+. But it would make sense to do what Dhaval said and use String.split(',') and then String.trim() each string.

Comment: This will match on `1, 1a` - which isn't really valid.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you mixed up the second part of your regex a bit. `^\d+,\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` should be what you need.

Here is a [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wM0tE2/2) sample.

- `\d+` matches one or more digits (an integer)
- `,\s`* matches comma, optionally followed by spaces
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` matches one or more digits, optionally followed by a dot and one or more digits (an integer or float)

Note1: This will not match negative numbers. You could adjust your regex to `^-?\d+,\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` if this is required

Note2: This will not match `.1` as a float, which might be a valid float. You could adjust your regex to `^\d+,\s*(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)$` if this is required.

Answer (score 2):

First split string by ","

```
var entry = "123,123.4";
var entryArray = entry.split(',');
```

then just check entryArray items using following function I got from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885844/2169925)

```
function isFloat(n) {
    return n === +n && n !== (n|0);
}

function isInteger(n) {
    return n === +n && n === (n|0);
}
```

And here is full recipe

```
function isFloat(n) {
    return n === +n && n !== (n|0);
}

function isInteger(n) {
    return n === +n && n === (n|0);
}

function isValidInput(input){
    if (!input) {return false};
    var inputArray = input.split(',');
    inputArray = inputArray.map(function(item){
        return item.trim();
    })
    inputArray = inputArray.filter(function(n){
        var number = parseFloat(n);
        return number && (isInteger(parseFloat(n)) || isFloat(parseFloat(n)) )
    })
    return (inputArray.length === 2)
}
isValidInput("55,55.44");
```

Comment: The link used is from 2010, there are much more modern method now, such as [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

Comment: There's a million ways to verify whether a number is an int or a float, that doesn't make this method less valid.

Comment: @Andrew It's not less valid but it might be less efficient, and anyway it seems wasteful to write code when there's a native function that already does the same thing.

Comment: @Aaron Number.isInteger()  is not cross browser supported, you have to write Polyfill for that.

Comment: @Dhaval It's [defined in ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isinteger), which is usually good enough. However, according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Browser_compatibility) it looks like you're right and its support is lagging behind :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+,\s?\d+\.?\d*$
```

Will be valid to

```
1234, 1234
123, 123.45
```

And Invalid To

```
abd, 123
123, abc
abc, abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?:\d{1,3})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

> 652.16 valid
>
> .12 invalid
>
> 511.22 valid
>
> 1.23 valid
>
> 12.3 valid
>
> 12.34 valid