# Using Meteor's Match.Integer pattern with form input

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, integer

I'm learning how to use Meteor and am currently looking at using the `check` package to validate user input, using the tutorial at: http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/methods/.

I'm trying to use the `Match.Integer` pattern inside a method (`addPlayer`, say) to ensure data entered into a particular field (passed to the `addPlayer` method via the `initialScore` parameter) is a valid integer, which works fine when calling `addPlayer` through the console. However, when entering data via the form (which calls `addPlayer` when submitted) this doesn't work properly since the entered data is of the `String` type.

I was considering applying the `Number` function to the entered data before using `Match.Integer` but am thinking this is a bad idea since some non-numerical values would be accepted.

Would it be a good idea to have my own `isInteger` function, such as:

```
function isInteger(n) {
  return n == +n && n == (n|0);
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885844/3806231, but with `===` replaced with `==` to allow form data, of `String` type, to be checked)

and call this before applying the `Number` function as described above? For example:

```
Meteor.methods({

  'addPlayer': function(initialScore) {
    if (isInteger(initialScore)) {
      check(Number(initialScore), Match.Integer);
    }
  }

});
```

Something like this seems quite long-winded and expensive just to validate an integer. Before using Meteor, I would just call something like the `isInteger` method, but now I'm using Meteor I want to make use of the available packages to save writing some of this standard validation code myself.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If it's a number field, don't even allow the user to enter non-numbers to begin with! Make an onChange event and check the regex against `/[0-9]/ ` (or `/[\-0-9]/ ` if negative integers are allowed).

Comment: @MichelFloyd Oh yeah, thanks. Thinking I could do that inside a jQuery `.on('input')` event so it fires at every change of the text rather than only when losing focus, or possibly put it into a `Match.Where` inside a `check`.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Also, should the `onChange` event handler code be sent to just the client?

Comment: Yes, just do initial validation on the client in the UI before you send it to the server and then check it again on the server using `check()`. Give the user feedback asap which means avoid the server roundtrip for typos/fat fingers.

Comment: You don't need a jQuery event handler, you can just have a Template event.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Oh yeah, forgot about that. Also that'll allow me to use the Bootstrap success/error validation states for the form inputs. And oh yeah, forgot about the `Template` events as well :P