# Why are my test for checking floats keeps returning false?

Tags: javascript

I created a javascript method that checks if a number is a float. Each time I test the method for a float it keeps returning FALSE. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be really appreciated!

Below is my code.. Thanks!

```
function isFloat(n){

    var patt =  new RegExp('[+-]([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+');
    return patt.test(n)
}


console.log(isFloat(12.40));
```

Comment: Why do you use `new Regexp(...)` When you can just use `/.../g`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Why don't you try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3886106/693275

Comment: See, you can make a regex by inserting it inside 2 `/`s like I wrote above. Then you can add flags at the end of it

Comment: Your regex looks like you are trying to check if a string is numeric, but your description is like you want to check if a number is not an integer. I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a much easier way to check if a number is a float. Just compare the floored value against the original value. If they're the same, it's an integer.

```js
function isFloat(n) {
  return Math.floor(n) !== n;
}

console.log(isFloat(1));
console.log(isFloat(1.2));
console.log(isFloat(12));
console.log(isFloat(12.4));
```

This will work if, and only if, you only use it on numbers. You can perform an additional check if you're worried about someone passing in non-numbers.

```
function isFloat(n) {
  return typeof n === 'number' && Math.floor(n) !== n;
}
```

Or you can simplify this even further by using [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger), provided you're running an environment that supports it.

```js
function isFloat(n) {
  return typeof n === 'number' && !Number.isInteger(n);
}

console.log(isFloat(1));
console.log(isFloat(1.2));
console.log(isFloat(12));
console.log(isFloat(12.4));
console.log(isFloat('a'));
```

Comment: FYI `isFloat('a') === true` (don't you just love `NaN`?! :P)

Comment: @PhilVarg `12.0 === 12` so it's effectively an integer, as long as you care about actual values and not string representations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike C!

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx is wrong, it should be

```
/[+-]?\d+\.\d+/g
```

Also, as others noted, this is not the best solution for this. Use `!Number.isInteger(num)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `toString` does not insert `'+'` before a number:

```
12.40.toString(); // "12.4", not "+12.4"
```

So you could use a regular expression like

```
new RegExp('[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+');
```

However, I recommend [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18082/1529630)