# Javascript - quick way to check if 10 variables are between 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript

I know there's probably an easy loop for this, but can't think of it.

I have 10 scores, and I need to validate them by making sure they are between 0 and 1 (plenty of decimals).

The input is pretty loose, so blank, null, alphanumeric values can be in there.

Right now I simply have

```
if (!(score1>=0 && score1<=1)){var result="error"} else
if (!(score2>=0 && score2<=1)){var result="error"} else
if (!(score3>=0 && score3<=1)){var result="error"} ...
```

Maybe not the most elegant formatting but -- there's got to be a way to loop through this, right?

Comment: Put your scores in array then you can use a `for` loop to check each one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [every <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and place your numbers in an array.

```js
var score1 = 0.89;
var score2 = 0.75;
var score3 = 0.64;
var booleanResult = [score1,score2,score3].every(s => s >= 0 && s<= 1);
console.log(booleanResult);
```

This answer uses an arrow function:

---

*Alternatively*, this is an example of using every with a classic function callback

```js
var score1 = 0.89;
var score2 = 0.75;
var score3 = 0.64;
var booleanResult = [score1,score2,score3].every(function(s){ return s >= 0 && s<= 1 });
console.log(booleanResult);
```

Comment: Great answer, but important to note that this uses ES6 features which may not be compatible with OP's target browsers.

Comment: @samrap - Yes, that is why I included the link to the arrow function topic in Docs, it also includes which browsers and versions support arrow functions. That said, I included an alternative example here to see how a classic callback would be used, although I assume that many users are familiar with this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an array `var numbersArray = [var1, var2, var3 ...]` iterate through the array and check the if, you can create a "flag" variable with a boolean and if any of the numbers result in error then change the flag value and break the for...

That's it, pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this

```
var array = [var1, var2, varn ...];
for (let arr of array) {
    if (typeof arr === 'number')
        if (arr >= your condition)
            ... the rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if (!(window["score"+i.toString()]>=0 && window["score"+i.toString()]<=1)){var result="error"}
}
```

Here is a fiddle to prove the concept: https://jsfiddle.net/gL902rtu/1/

And as mentionned by @Rick Hitchcock, the score variable has to be global (see the fiddle for example)

Proof of concept:

```
score1 = 0.5;
score2 = 0.1;
score3 = 0.5;
score4 = 0.8;
score5 = 0.9;
score6 = 0.4;
score7 = 0.10;
score8 = 0.4;
score9 = 0.5;
score10 = 0.8;
result = "noerror";
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  if (!(window["score"+i.toString()]>=0 && window["score"+i.toString()]<=1)){ 
    result="error"
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Note that this would work with your code but the easiest way would be for sure to store your score in a array and loop trough it, it's pretty much what arrays are for.

You can have more information about array over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: `toString()` isn't necessary here.  (Also, you should point out that this works only if the variables are in the global scope.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function for this, where the first argument is minimum, second is maximum, then the rest are numbers to check, then using `.filter()` to find invalid numbers:

```js
function CheckRange(min, max) {
    if (arguments.length > 2) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
     return args.slice(2).filter(function(x) {
            return x < min || x > max;
        }).length == 0;
    }
    return true;
}
console.log(CheckRange(0, 1, 0.25, '', null, 0.7, 0.12, 0.15));
```

In the above code empty or null are treated as valid, easy enough to disallow them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const scores = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

scores.forEach(function(score){
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer
    let isFloat = ( Number(score) === score && score % 1 !== 0 );

    if (isFloat && (score > 0 && score < 1))
        console.log("It's correct!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting your scores into an array would be the best starting point. You can do this easily like:

```
var allScores = [score1, score2, score3];
```

Once you have an array, if you are targeting a platfrom with ES5 support [check here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5%20check%20here) then you can use the filter function of an array:

```
var errorScores = allScores.filter(function(s) {
  return !(parseInt(s) >= 0 && parseInt(s) <= 1)
});

if (errorScores.length > 0) {
  // Do some error handling.
}
```

[Here is an example of this on code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVaeja)

Alternatively, if you can't use filter then you can do a loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allScores.length; i++) {
  var score = allScores[i];
  if (!(parseInt(score) >= 0 && parseInt(score) <= 1)) {
    // Do some error handling.
    document.write('something went wrong!');
  }
}
```

[Here is an example of this on code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNjoGL)

Note the use of parseInt above to handle, null, '' and other text values. Invalid numbers will be parsed to `NaN` which will fail to meet the condition.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using lodash, you can use

_.pluck(window, function(key, value) {}) and then check if key contains variable name and value is less than 10.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i=i) { // i=i means do nothing
   i++;
   if( eval("score" + i + ">=0 && score" + i + "<=1") ) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

However, you should use some sort of type-checking; `eval` is considered unsafe in certain contexts.

Comment: Mine does not require seperate variables; the OP asked to do it in seperate vars, I do not know why so many answers are not like this.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but many programmers consider `eval` as "evil" due to potential security concerns.  Also, why not use `i++` as the third `for` argument instead of putting it within the loop?

Comment: Loops are hard to loop around my head; there isn't always a "1 to 10" in every programming language. Oh, and I did not know about the evil eval, so that makes sense now. Thanks.