# Round number to two dp unless whole number?

Tags: javascript

(UPDATE: To all those saying this is a dupe and voting to close, it is *not* a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary): the difference is that I want to display 1 dp numbers to 2 dp. It may well be a dupe of some other question, but please post a link if it is!)

I want to display a price in JavaScript. I would like to display an integer if the original number is a whole number. Or if it's a float, I would like to display it rounded to two decimal places.

```
input  |  output
24     |  24
24.231 |  24.23
24.2   |  24.20
```

I've tried `Math.round(num * 100) / 100`, but that doesn't convert `24.2` correctly.

I've also tried `.toFixed(2)` but that converts `24` to `24.00`, which isn't what I want.

Any ideas? This must be a very common problem when displaying prices.

Comment: It's more common to always have the .00, even for whole number prices

Comment: Check if it's a [whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer) then use `tofixed` if it's not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: @Rajesh it's not a duplicate of that qu - I want to show two dp for numbers with one dp. Have updated question to make clear.

Comment: @EKW thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Richard If you see the selected answer, it does what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/3783478

Comment: @Rajesh that's not correct, sorry. Have you tried `Math.round(24.2 * 100) / 100`? It gives `24.2`, not `24.20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably gonna need to use an if statement for this.

```
if(Number.isInteger(price)) {
    return price;
} else {
    return price.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the number is whole, if so then convert to a string without decimals, else convert to a string with 2 decimals.

```js
console.log(displayRounded(23.237));
console.log(displayRounded(23.231));
console.log(displayRounded(24.2));
console.log(displayRounded(24));

function displayRounded(price) {
  return Number.isInteger(price) ? price.toString() : price.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: You should look for dupes first and then if not found, then only answer them. Its a bad practice to answer a dupe

Comment: @Rajesh it's not a dupe.