# Angular - number pipe if there's a value

Tags: html, angular, firebase

I'm creating shop app and i have problem with my number pipe. Is there any way to enable format number like **64,90** to set two digits after the decimal point only if there's value in db like **64.9** and if it's 60 in db, to show only 60 without digits after ?

```
<p>{{ product.price | number: '1.2-2' }} zł</p>
```

This pipe shows my correct 64.90 but not correct 60.00

Comment: Not sure about the capabilities of the number pipe syntax itself, but you could easily fix this issue with two if statements: `<p><ng-template *ngIf="product.price.indexOf('.') > -1">{{ product.price | number: '1.2-2' }}</ng-template><ng-template *ngIf="product.price.indexOf('.') === 0">{{ product.price }}</ng-template></p>`

Comment: Why would you want to alter between having decimal places and not - doesn't sound like very good UX design imo.

Comment: @user3492940 indexOf is not a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'floatNumbers'
})
export class FloatNumbersPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    const isFloat = (n) => {
      return n === +n && n !== (n|0);
    }

    return isFloat(+value) ? (+value).toFixed(2) : value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! But can u actually write what this return is doing? It's working but i have problem with understanding that

Comment: It's if shorthand. We check if value (we need to parse it to number by adding +) is float, if so - we return that value with two decimals places (we need also to parse it to number to get toFixed method) in otherwise we just return that value. Here you are!

Comment: Actually i was asking about this: n === +n && n !== (n|0) this is so hard for me to understand. I see two condiditions here but dk what is happening there

Comment: It's function from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885844/3986118 You can check all discussion for better understanding.