# Identifying a variable and casting to int

Tags: javascript, casting, floating-point, integer

I have troubles with a variable in JavaScript that I want to be `int`.
In the beginning, it looked like an `int`, then I did some diagnostics and found out it is not.
Ultimately, I want to cast it to `int`.

This is the code I used:

```
console.log(variable);
var isInt = variable % 1 === 0;
console.log('The variable is int?');
console.log(isInt);
var isFloat = +variable && variable !== (variable|0);
console.log('The variable is float?');
console.log(isFloat);
```

And these are the results:

```
2,365
The variable is int?
false
The variable is float?
NaN
```

The line for checking if the variable is `float` I got it from this question:
[How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)
It is the second answer.

`NaN` means my variable is probably a `string`?

EDIT:
My question is different from the one offered as a solution, as i am not sure if my variable is float or integer, thus i am trying to identify it first.
I picked parts from answers from that question, but it did nto work.

Comment: You know that Number.isInteger exists right?

Comment: @ErtanKara yeah. The linked question not only has an answer that says that but also offers the polyfill, so it can be implemented even if the environment doesn't support it yet.

Comment: you can simply log typeof variable to check the type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Comment: `2,365` is a string. `2.365` could be float or string.

Comment: good observation

Comment: NaN means "not a number". +variable casts it to number, and as ChrisG said, it's a string with comma.

Comment: @SamGhatak thanks! I didn't know that. Turns out it is a string.

Comment: Concerning your edit: the question dupe STILL HAS AN ANSWER FOR YOU. The answer you picked explicitly only checks variables that are already numeric. The accepted answer already has a solution for an unknown type of variable. There is another solution that suggests using built in (ES6) checks and provides ES5 code that achieves exactly the same.

Comment: What is the correct thing to do then, for my situation? Should i accept the other answer and mark mine as duplicate?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Everything you've said so far makes it seem like it's a complete duplicate. You need to know if a variable is numeric and which type or a string representation of a JS numeric type. Both of those have answers in the question you linked. Unless you're asking something different, I would consider it a dupe.

Comment: Now there is no button to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @vlaz While I tend to agree, this question is about parsing a string that uses a comma as decimal symbol. So strictly speaking not a dupe.

Comment: @ChrisG Maybe i should edit the title or the question?

Comment: @user1584421 I don't know, maybe. The problem is that your question is essentially two separate questions due to the `,` with the second being about turning a float to an int, not so much detecting what it is. It's almost an XY problem, and everybody is only focusing on the Y part.

Comment: Is you actual question something like: I'm getting this: `{ "value": "2,365" }` and I want to turn `value` into an int?

Comment: @ChrisG I guess it is.. But until i arrived in that conclusion, i had to first pass through the mental space of "i have to identify what this variable is"...

Answer (score 2):

> Note: `parseInt()` will cut off any and all decimals!

If you're getting "numbers" (strings) with `,` as decimal symbol, and you want to turn them into integers by *rounding*, you can use this:

```js
function toInt(x) {
  if (!isNaN(x)) return Math.round(x);
  if (typeof x == "string") x = x.replace(",", ".");
  return Math.round(parseFloat(x));
}

console.log(toInt(5));
console.log(toInt(5.5));
console.log(toInt("5"));
console.log(toInt("5.5"));
console.log(toInt("5,5"));
```

Shorter version:

```
const toInt = x => Math.round(isNaN(x) ? (typeof x == "string" ? x.replace(",", ".") : x) : x);
```

Comment: To do the replace, you have to be sure that the commas are fraction separators. They could separate thousands in some cultures, so `"1,000,000"` represents one *million* not simply *one* which the function returns.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried your short version but it did not work. After i run the command, i typed console.log(typeof variable); and i get "function".

Comment: Then tried this: "variable = parseInt(variable);". And it worked!

Comment: Yep, you need to use the return value. Wait, what, `parseInt`? Mine works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eakfpcyq/ (mine rounds the value, parseInt cuts off decimals!)

Comment: I will do further testing and i will post here the results later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the first line try

```
console.log(typeof variable)
```

and this will tell you the type of the variable is **string or not** which might be causing **NaN** in the last check

Comment: It won't tell if it's float or int, it will only tell if it's a number or other types.

Comment: in this case it will tell if its a string after all, thanks for pointing out .. updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! This helped me identify it as a string!