# How to check different types of integer datatype in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Mysql has the different integer datatype like, INT, **SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT**. Is there any way to detect the number is falling under which data type in JavaScript?

Comment: i would just hard code it with greater than and less than

Comment: @RolandStarke — That could tell you the smallest DB datatype that would hold the number you had, but it wouldn't tell you the actual datatype.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript only has one datatype for numbers: [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

([BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is proposed for a future version of JS).

So, all else being equal: You can't.

Your database API might provide a mechanism that would expose that information, but it would depend on the database API you were using.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Actually I am creating the YAML file by reading the CSV input (using node js). So in the  `type` attribute I have to mention the number data type.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there is no such categorization as such **int** or **float**, there is only **number**, more details about datatypes in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Further if you need to check weather the value is **int** of **float**, you can the answer in following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)